# Why doesn’t deleting from a Javascript array change its length?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
data.Dealer.car[0]
data.Dealer.car[1]
data.Dealer.car[2]
```

If I do this:

```
alert(data.Dealer.car.length);
delete data.Dealer.car[1];
alert(data.Dealer.car.length);
```

It gives me the same count each time. Does the removed element still exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson — It doesn’t seem to be an exact duplicate. The question you linked is asking for the differences between `delete` and `Array.prototype.splice`, whereas this question is basically asking why deleting an element from an array (thus making it sparse) won’t reduce its length.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaScript arrays aren't sparse, if you have a 0 and a 2, then element 1 must exist. Meaning the `length` is going to be 3.

Comment: Yeah, and the element 2 will be undefined .

Comment: What happens when you delete something at the last index in the array?

Comment: The length will be untouched if you delete the last element. You can set the length to shrink the array to any size you want.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript arrays can, in fact, be sparse.

Comment: JS arrays *can* be sparse. Sparse arrays are arrays that have one or more uninitialized elements. For example `let arr = ['foo' , , 'bar']` is a sparse array, so it has length `3`, even though `arr[1]` does not have a value.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to remove an item, use the `splice` method:

```
alert(data.Dealer.car.length);
data.Dealer.car.splice(1, 1);
alert(data.Dealer.car.length);
```

But notice that the indices have changed.

Answer (score 5):

Array.shift() would remove the first item from the array and make it shorter. 
Array.pop() will remove the last item.

Answer (score 5):

Building on what @Ray Hidayat posted:

JavaScript arrays **are** sparse. If you have an array of length 3, deleting the reference at [1] will simply "unset" that item, not remove it from the array, or update that array's length.  You could accomplish the same with

```
myArray = [0, , 2, , , , ];  // length 6; last three items undefined
```

Here's a Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/WYKDz/

NOTE: removing items from the middle of large arrays can be computationally intensive.  See this post for more info:
[Fastest way to delete one entry from the middle of Array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638381/fastest-way-to-delete-one-entry-from-the-middle-of-array)

Comment: That's not what sparse means.

Comment: @DaraJavaherian: That is what sparse means. (No? At least say what your definition of it is…)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];

alert( arr.splice( 2, 1 ) ); // alerts 2, the element you're removing
alert( arr ) // alerts 0,1,3,4  - the remaining elements
```

here's a [MDC reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. fixed this now as the array was still allocated.

I needed to basically do:

```
var newCar = new Array();
for (i = 0 ; i < tblSize -2; i ++)
{
    newCar[i]=data.Dealer.car[i];
}
data.Dealer.car = newCar;
```

Comment: You want to remove the last item? Just use: data.Dealer.car.pop();