# Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, delete-operator, array-splice

What is the difference between using [the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) on the array element as opposed to using [the `Array.splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

For example:

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

delete myArray[1];
//  or
myArray.splice (1, 1);
```

Why even have the splice method if I can delete array elements like I can with objects?

Comment: For `.splice` in loops, have a look at this question: [Delete from array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362412/delete-from-array-in-javascript).

Comment: @andynormancx Yes, but this answer was posted just the day after, and got so many more votes - I'd say it's better written, that must be it.

Comment: @andynormancx — It doesn’t seem to be an exact duplicate. The question you linked is basically asking why deleting an element from an array (thus making it sparse) won’t reduce its length. This question is asking for the differences between `delete` and `Array.prototype.splice`.

Comment: @chharvey agreed, more importantly though how can this question have been posted 9 years ago ! Makes me feel old to be back here commenting on it

Comment: [JavaScript: the first 20 years](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3386327) mentioned   "JavaScript 1.1 adds the delete, typeof, and void operators. In JavaScript 1.1 the delete operator simply sets its variable or object-property operand to the value null. " & splice was added to 1.2 "The Array push, pop, shift, unshift, and splice were directly modeled on like-named Perl array functions."

Answer (score 1820, accepted):

`delete` will delete the object property, but will not reindex the array or update its length. This makes it appears as if it is undefined:

```
> myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
> delete myArray[0]
  true
> myArray[0]
  undefined
```

Note that it is not in fact set to the value `undefined`, rather the property is removed from the array, making it *appear* undefined. The Chrome dev tools make this distinction clear by printing `empty` when logging the array.

```
> myArray[0]
  undefined
> myArray
  [empty, "b", "c", "d"]
```

[`myArray.splice(start, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) actually removes the element, reindexes the array, and changes its length.

```
> myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
> myArray.splice(0, 2)
  ["a", "b"]
> myArray
  ["c", "d"]
```

Comment: Actually, `delete` *does* remove the element, but does not reindex the array or update its length (which is already implied by the former since the length is always the highest index+1).

Comment: JSlint doesn't like `delete myArray[0]` syntax saying "**Expected an operator and instead saw 'delete'.**" Using `splice` is recommended.

Comment: @Eye: Actually, JSLint is just complaining about the lack of a semicolon on the previous line. And you can’t really recommend one over the other, since they do completely different things…

Comment: @CédricGuillemette: Because `splice` can also be used to insert elements.

Comment: gotcha if you are going to remove multiple elements, as index of array changes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425009/remove-multiple-elements-from-array-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: *"Delete in this case will only set the element as undefined:"* No, that is flatly incorrect. There's a fundamental difference between `delete myArray[0]` and `myArray[0] = undefined`. In the former case, the property is removed from the array object entirely. In the second case, the property remains, with the value `undefined`.

Comment: I understand the distinction, thanks. But how can I prove that detail in the code example? Which ever way I try and inspect the array it appears the same.

Comment: FYI, the Chrome dev tools shows the keyword `empty` instead of `undefined` to improve the distinction between an actually deleted (or uninitialized) array element versus an element that has the real value of `undefined`. Note that as I say this I mean it only *displays* as `empty`, and does not refer to a real value called `empty` (which does not exist).

Comment: your_array = ['aa','bb','cc'];
//-- exp. delete the first one or index 0   
your_array.splice(0, 1);
it print :  ['bb','cc'];

Comment: is there any way to remove the empty elements from my array after using the delete method

Answer (score 352):

## Array.remove() Method

**John Resig**, creator of jQuery created a very handy `Array.remove` method that I always use it in my projects.

```
// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

and here's some examples of how it could be used:

```
// Remove the second item from the array
array.remove(1);
// Remove the second-to-last item from the array
array.remove(-2);
// Remove the second and third items from the array
array.remove(1,2);
// Remove the last and second-to-last items from the array
array.remove(-2,-1);
```

[John's website](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/)

Comment: +1 For Array.remove(). However it's not happy being passed string arguments (unlike most Array methods, eg `[1,2,3].slice('1'); // =[2,3]`), so it's safer to change it to `var rest = this.slice(parseInt(to || from) + 1 || this.length);`

Comment: I found that this was causing an asynchronous problem. Does the thread get given up before the this.push.apply() ?

Comment: @tomwrong, there are no threads in javascript, and the function executes `this.push.apply(this, rest)`, then returns the value it returned

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question at all.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to return the elements that were removed instead of the new count.

Comment: Why not just use splice()? The name of this function, the parameter names and the results aren't obvious. My recommendation is to just use splice(index,length) - (see Andy Hume's answer)

Comment: Function provided above works as explained, yet it creates unwanted side effects when iterating through array with `for(var i in array)` cycle. I've removed it and used splice instead.

Comment: @auco Look at John's website in the link above. It can do negative values and remove single items with a single parameter.

Comment: alexykot, got the same strange error as you did. Chrome console said there was some "range" error when a lib of mine iterated through the array with `for (var i in array)`. So I declared the John-remove function separately and not on `Array.prototype`.

Comment: If you want to iterate an array, you should use a for(i=0;i<.length;i++) instead of the for(i in array). The former will work for arrays, the latter will work for objects (unless all your object indices are integers but length won't exist). The former also won't get you the extra prototype methods (should they not set the enumerable property to false).

Comment: This does not remove multiple elements if they should be present.

Comment: MartinAndersson and alexykot - Lots of things cause issues when using `for...in` to loop through an Array's indices. That's because `for...in` is not a proper way to loop through Array indices :) `for...in` enumerates Object properties. Arrays may have more Object properties than just their indices. So if you're trying to loop through just indices and you're using `for...in` then you're doing it wrong. Use a sequential loop (e.g. `for (var i=0; i<myArr.length; i++)`), one of the Array methods (e.g. `myArr.map(...)`) or `for...of` to loop through Array indices.

Comment: Did he actually licensed a single function. JS community amazes me.

Comment: this answer deserves more love, i come from python background and this way to do it feels just like home.

thanks !

Comment: this answer would be improved if you explained the difference between John's 'remove', and splice.

Answer (score 109):

Because delete only removes the object from the element in the array, the length of the array won't change. Splice removes the object and shortens the array.

The following code will display "a", "b", "undefined", "d"

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; delete myArray[2];

for (var count = 0; count < myArray.length; count++) {
    alert(myArray[count]);
}
```

Whereas this will display "a", "b", "d"

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; myArray.splice(2,1);

for (var count = 0; count < myArray.length; count++) {
    alert(myArray[count]);
}
```

Comment: great example except the ambiguity in the second example by using 1,1 - the first 1 refers to the index in the array to start the splice, the second 1 is the number of elements to remove. So to remove 'c' from the original array, use `myArray.splice(2,1)`

Answer (score 77):

I stumbled onto this question while trying to understand how to remove every occurrence of an element from an Array. [Here's a comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/y5NbD/5/) of `splice` and `delete` for removing every `'c'` from the `items` Array.

```
var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

while (items.indexOf('c') !== -1) {
  items.splice(items.indexOf('c'), 1);
}

console.log(items); // ["a", "b", "d", "a", "b", "d"]

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

while (items.indexOf('c') !== -1) {
  delete items[items.indexOf('c')];
}

console.log(items); // ["a", "b", undefined, "d", "a", "b", undefined, "d"]
​
```

Answer (score 14):

From  [Core JavaScript 1.5 Reference > Operators > Special Operators > delete Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) :

> When you delete an array element, the
>   array length is not affected. For
>   example, if you delete a[3], a[4] is
>   still a[4] and a[3] is undefined. This
>   holds even if you delete the last
>   element of the array (delete
>   a[a.length-1]).

Answer (score 12):

As stated many times above, using `splice()` seems like a perfect fit. [Documentation at Mozilla:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The **`splice()`** method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.
>
> ```
> var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'sturgeon'];
>
> myFish.splice(2, 0, 'drum'); 
> // myFish is ["angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "sturgeon"]
>
> myFish.splice(2, 1); 
> // myFish is ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "sturgeon"]
> ```
>
> ## Syntax
>
> > ```
> > array.splice(start)
> > array.splice(start, deleteCount)
> > array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
> > ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> #### start
>
> Index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from the end.
>
> #### deleteCount
>
> An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> If deleteCount is omitted, deleteCount will be equal to `(arr.length - start).`
>
> #### item1, item2, ...
>
> The elements to add to the array, beginning at the start index. If you don't specify any elements, `splice()` will only remove elements from the array.
>
> ### Return value
>
> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 10):

`splice` will work with numeric indices.

whereas `delete` can be used against other kind of indices..

example:

```
delete myArray['text1'];
```

Comment: When you say 'any other kind of indices', you're not talking about arrays any more, but rather objects, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @YiJiang: Arrays are Objects. Indizes are properties. There is no difference.

Comment: @Bergi: `arr[2]` is the third element of array `arr`, while `arr['x']` is a property`x` of the object. It doesn't make much difference in actual use, but they are stored differently internally.

Answer (score 9):

It's probably also worth mentioning that splice only works on arrays. (Object properties can't be relied on to follow a consistent order.)

To remove the key-value pair from an object, delete is actually what you want:

```
delete myObj.propName;     // , or:
delete myObj["propName"];  // Equivalent.
```

Comment: delete doesn't reorder the array keys, so:

    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    delete arr[3];
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
        console.log(arr[i]);

will exhibit unexpected results.

Comment: This is true.  So unless you want to leave an undefined item at that location, DON'T use delete on an array's keys!  I originally added this comment to include a reference of the correct use of delete.

Comment: but why delete will throw unexpected result ??

Answer (score 9):

**delete Vs splice**

when you delete an item from an array

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4]; delete arr[2]; //result [1, 2, 3:, 4]
console.log(arr)
```

when you splice

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4]; arr.splice(1,1); //result [1, 3, 4]
console.log(arr);
```

in case of **delete** the **element is deleted** but the **index remains empty**

while in case of **splice** element is deleted and the **index of rest elements is reduced accordingly**

Answer (score 7):

The difference can be seen by logging the length of each array after the `delete` operator and `splice()` method are applied. For example:

### delete operator

```
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
delete trees[3];

console.log(trees); // ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", empty, "maple"]
console.log(trees.length); // 5
```

The `delete` operator removes the element from the array, but the "placeholder" of the element still exists. `oak` has been removed but it still takes space in the array. Because of this, the length of the array remains 5.

### splice() method

```
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
trees.splice(3,1);

console.log(trees); // ["redwood", "bay", "cedar", "maple"]
console.log(trees.length); // 4
```

The `splice()` method completely removes the target value **and** the "placeholder" as well. `oak` has been removed as well as the space it used to occupy in the array. The length of the array is now 4.

Comment: best answer here. regardless of performance or any other esoteric discussion, delete and splice are NOT the same. when you must have an element removed from the array whereby the array length reflects the number of actual elements, you only have choice between the two.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to iterate a large array and selectively delete elements, it would be expensive to call splice() for every delete because splice() would have to re-index subsequent elements every time. Because arrays are associative in Javascript, it would be more efficient to delete the individual elements then re-index the array afterwards.

You can do it by building a new array. e.g

```
function reindexArray( array )
{
       var result = [];
        for( var key in array )
                result.push( array[key] );
        return result;
};
```

But I don't think you can modify the key values in the original array, which would be more efficient - it looks like you might have to create a new array.

Note that you don't need to check for the "undefined" entries as they don't actually exist and the for loop doesn't return them. It's an artifact of the array printing that displays them as undefined. They don't appear to exist in memory.

It would be nice if you could use something like slice() which would be quicker, but it does not re-index. Anyone know of a better way?

---

Actually, you can probably do it in place as follows which is probably more efficient, performance-wise:

```
reindexArray : function( array )
{
    var index = 0;                          // The index where the element should be
    for( var key in array )                 // Iterate the array
    {
        if( parseInt( key ) !== index )     // If the element is out of sequence
        {
            array[index] = array[key];      // Move it to the correct, earlier position in the array
            ++index;                        // Update the index
        }
    }

    array.splice( index );  // Remove any remaining elements (These will be duplicates of earlier items)
},
```

Comment: I believe the ++index; needs to happen outside the 'if'. Making edit

Answer (score 6):

you can use something like this

```js
var my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
delete my_array[4];
console.log(my_array.filter(function(a){return typeof a !== 'undefined';})); // [1,2,3,4,6]
```

Comment: this is more intuitive than `slice` if you come from a functional background (probably less efficient, though).

Answer (score 6):

**delete** acts like a non real world situation, it just *removes* the item, but the array length stays the same:

example from node terminal:

```
> var arr = ["a","b","c","d"];
> delete arr[2]
true
> arr
[ 'a', 'b', , 'd', 'e' ]
```

Here is a function to remove an item of an array by index, using **slice()**, it takes the arr as the first arg, and the index of the member you want to delete as the second argument. As you can see, it actually deletes the member of the array, and will reduce the array length by 1

```
function(arr,arrIndex){
    return arr.slice(0,arrIndex).concat(arr.slice(arrIndex + 1));
}
```

What the function above does is take all the members up to the index, and all the members after the index , and concatenates them together, and returns the result.

Here is an example using the function above as a node module, seeing the terminal will be useful:

```
> var arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
> arr
[ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
> arr.length
4 
> var arrayRemoveIndex = require("./lib/array_remove_index");
> var newArray = arrayRemoveIndex(arr,arr.indexOf('c'))
> newArray
[ 'a', 'b', 'd' ] // c ya later
> newArray.length
3
```

please note that this will not work one array with dupes in it, because indexOf("c") will just get the first occurance, and only splice out and remove the first "c" it finds.

Answer (score 4):

## Performance

There are already many nice answer about functional differences - so here I want to focus on performance. Today (2020.06.25) I perform tests for Chrome 83.0, Safari 13.1 and Firefox 77.0 for solutions mention in question and additionally from chosen answers

### Conclusions

- the `splice` (B) solution is fast for small and big arrays
- the `delete` (A) solution is fastest for big and medium fast for small arrays
- the `filter` (E) solution is fastest on Chrome and Firefox for small arrays (but slowest on Safari, and slow for big arrays)
- solution D is quite slow
- solution C not works for big arrays in Chrome and Safari

  ```js
  function C(arr, idx) {
    var rest = arr.slice(idx + 1 || arr.length);
    arr.length = idx < 0 ? arr.length + idx : idx;
    arr.push.apply(arr, rest);
    return arr;
  }


  // Crash test

  let arr = [...'abcdefghij'.repeat(100000)]; // 1M elements

  try {
   C(arr,1)
  } catch(e) {console.error(e.message)}
  ```

[image]

### Details

I perform following tests for solutions
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/860099)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/860099)
[C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815010/860099)
[D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24846748/860099)
E (my)

- for small array (4 elements) - you can run test [HERE](https://jsbench.me/6ykbr1kku8)
- for big array (1M elements) - you can run test [HERE](https://jsbench.me/ngkbtudod2/1)

```js
function A(arr, idx) {
  delete arr[idx];
  return arr;
}

function B(arr, idx) {
  arr.splice(idx,1);
  return arr;
}

function C(arr, idx) {
  var rest = arr.slice(idx + 1 || arr.length);
  arr.length = idx < 0 ? arr.length + idx : idx;
  arr.push.apply(arr, rest);
  return arr;
}

function D(arr,idx){
    return arr.slice(0,idx).concat(arr.slice(idx + 1));
}

function E(arr,idx) {
  return arr.filter((a,i) => i !== idx);
}

myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

[A,B,C,D,E].map(f => console.log(`${f.name} ${JSON.stringify(f([...myArray],1))}`));
```

```html
This snippet only presents used solutions
```

Example results for Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why not just filter? I think it is the most clear way to consider the arrays in js.

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(item){
    return item.anProperty != whoShouldBeDeleted
});
```

Comment: What about an array with hundreds (if not thousands) of records where only 3 of them need to be removed?

Comment: good point. i use this method for sparse arrays whose length is not more than 200 or 300 and performs very well. However, i think libraries like underline should be preferred if you have to manage such greater arrays.

Comment: However, it seems much nicer than `delete` or `slice` to me.

Answer (score 3):

They're different things that have different purposes.

`splice` is array-specific and, when used for deleting, removes entries from the array *and* moves all the previous entries up to fill the gap. (It can also be used to insert entries, or both at the same time.) `splice` will change the `length` of the array (assuming it's not a no-op call: `theArray.splice(x, 0)`).

`delete` is not array-specific; it's designed for use on objects: It removes a property (key/value pair) from the object you use it on. It only applies to arrays because standard (e.g., non-typed) arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)*, they're objects with special handling for certain properties, such as those whose names are "array indexes" (which are [defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type) as string names "...whose numeric value `i` is in the range `+0 ≤ i < 2^32-1`") and `length`. When you use `delete` to remove an array entry, all it does is remove the entry; it doesn't move other entries following it up to fill the gap, and so the array becomes "sparse" (has some entries missing entirely). It has no effect on `length`.

A couple of the current answers to this question incorrectly state that using `delete` "sets the entry to `undefined`". That's not correct. It *removes* the entry (property) entirely, leaving a gap.

Let's use some code to illustrate the differences:

```js
console.log("Using `splice`:");
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(a.length);            // 5
a.splice(0, 1);
console.log(a.length);            // 4
console.log(a[0]);                // "b"
```

```js
console.log("Using `delete`");
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(a.length);            // 5
delete a[0];
console.log(a.length);            // still 5
console.log(a[0]);                // undefined
console.log("0" in a);            // false
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(0)); // false
```

```js
console.log("Setting to `undefined`");
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(a.length);            // 5
a[0] = undefined;
console.log(a.length);            // still 5
console.log(a[0]);                // undefined
console.log("0" in a);            // true
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(0)); // true
```

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: I just came across your article arrays in JavaScript aren't really arrays at all, so basically it was the same  as [lua array](https://www.lua.org/pil/11.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

Others have already properly compared `delete` with `splice`.

Another interesting comparison is `delete` versus `undefined`: a deleted array item uses less memory than one that is just set to `undefined`;

For example, this code will not finish:

```
let y = 1;
let ary = [];
console.log("Fatal Error Coming Soon");
while (y < 4294967295)
{
    ary.push(y);
    ary[y] = undefined;
    y += 1;
}
console(ary.length);
```

It produces this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.
```

So, as you can see `undefined` actually takes up heap memory.

However, if you also `delete` the ary-item (instead of just setting it to `undefined`), the code will slowly finish:

```
let x = 1;
let ary = [];
console.log("This will take a while, but it will eventually finish successfully.");
while (x < 4294967295)
{
    ary.push(x);
    ary[x] = undefined;
    delete ary[x];
    x += 1;
}
console.log(`Success, array-length: ${ary.length}.`);
```

These are extreme examples, but they make a point about `delete` that I haven't seen anyone mention anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I have two methods.

Simple one:

```js
arr = arr.splice(index,1)
```

Second one:

```js
arr = arr.filter((v,i)=>i!==index)
```

The advantage to the second one is you can remove a value (all, not just first instance like most)

```js
arr = arr.filter((v,i)=>v!==value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function remove_array_value(array, value) {
    var index = array.indexOf(value);
    if (index >= 0) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
        reindex_array(array);
    }
}
function reindex_array(array) {
   var result = [];
    for (var key in array) {
        result.push(array[key]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

example:

```
var example_arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'];   // length = 3
remove_array_value(example_arr, 'banana');
```

banana is deleted and array length = 2

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are two ways to do this

1. using splice()

   `arrayObject.splice(index, 1);`
2. using delete

   `delete arrayObject[index];`

But I always suggest to use splice for array objects and delete for object attributes because delete does not update array length.

Answer (score 2):

If you have small array you can use `filter`:

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
myArray = myArray.filter(x => x !== 'b');
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, imagine we have this array below:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Let's do delete first:

```
delete arr[1];
```

and this is the result:

```
[1, empty, 3, 4, 5];
```

**empty!** and let's get it:

```
arr[1]; //undefined
```

So means just the value deleted and it's **undefined** now, so length is the same, also it will return **true**...

Let's reset our array and do it with splice this time:

```
arr.splice(1, 1);
```

and this is the result this time:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5];
```

As you see the array length changed and `arr[1]` is **3** now...

Also this will return the deleted item in an Array which is `[3]` in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple :-

When you **delete** any element in an array, it will delete the value of the position mentioned and makes it empty/undefined but the position exist in the array.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5];

function del() {
  delete arr[3];
  console.log(arr);
}
del(arr);
```

where as in **splice** prototype the arguments are as follows. //arr.splice(position to start the delete , no. of items to delete)

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5];

function spl() {
  arr.splice(0, 2);
// arr.splice(position to start the delete , no. of items to delete)
  console.log(arr);
}
spl(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOf` accepts also a reference type. Suppose the following scenario:

```js
var arr = [{item: 1}, {item: 2}, {item: 3}];
var found = find(2, 3); //pseudo code: will return [{item: 2}, {item:3}]
var l = found.length;

while(l--) {
   var index = arr.indexOf(found[l])
      arr.splice(index, 1);
   }
   
console.log(arr.length); //1
```

Differently:

```
var item2 = findUnique(2); //will return {item: 2}
var l = arr.length;
var found = false;
  while(!found && l--) {
  found = arr[l] === item2;
}

console.log(l, arr[l]);// l is index, arr[l] is the item you look for
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
delete myArray[1]; // ['a', undefined, 'c', 'd']. Then use lodash compact method to remove false, null, 0, "", undefined and NaN
myArray = _.compact(myArray); ['a', 'c', 'd'];
```

Hope this helps. 
Reference: https://lodash.com/docs#compact

Comment: Should someone stumble on this wondering about `compact`... no need for lodash. Try `myArray.filter(function(n){return n;})`

Answer (score 0):

If the desired element to delete is in the middle (say we want to delete 'c', which its index is 1), you can use:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'];
var indexToDelete = 1;
var newArray = arr.slice(0,indexToDelete).combine(arr.slice(indexToDelete+1, arr.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#without) can use:
`myArray = _.without(myArray, itemToRemove)`

Or as I use in Angular2

```
import { without } from 'lodash';
...
myArray = without(myArray, itemToRemove);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> **delete**: delete will delete the object property, but will not reindex
>   the array or update its length. This makes it appears as if it is
>   undefined:
>
> **splice**: actually removes the element, reindexes the array, and changes
>   its length.

Delete element from last

```
arrName.pop();
```

Delete element from first

```
arrName.shift();
```

Delete from middle

```
arrName.splice(starting index,number of element you wnt to delete);

Ex: arrName.splice(1,1);
```

Delete one element from last

```
arrName.splice(-1);
```

Delete by using array index number

```
 delete arrName[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function deleteFromArray(array, indexToDelete){
  var remain = new Array();
  for(var i in array){
    if(array[i] == indexToDelete){
      continue;
    }
    remain.push(array[i]);
  }
  return remain;
}

myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
deleteFromArray(myArray , 0);
```

// result : myArray = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

Comment: @ChrisDennis why? (no sarcasm or malice intended, this is a sincere question)

Comment: Besides the fact that this answer doesn't address the OP's question