# Find all matching regex patterns and index of the match in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find `/AA/` pattern in `AA-AA-AA` subject string. I need to get the matching string and the position (index) of the match.

I have looked at [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). It only returns the first match:

```js
/AA/g.exec('AA-AA-AA')
```

Comment: Introducing http://jsfiddle.net - a place you can go for all your HTML/CSS/JS demoing needs.

Comment: is that you want ? http://rubular.com/r/X9NQ4h1xYH

Comment: not really. my problem is not writing the pattern, but getting the information i need after search was performed - the index values of the results to be exact

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`exec()` only returns a single match. To get all matches with a `g`​lobal regexp, you have to call it repeatedly, eg.:

```
var match, indexes= [];
while (match= r.exec(value))
    indexes.push([match.index, match.index+match[0].length]);
```

Comment: Great. Made me that much wiser

Comment: Why not use `str.match(regex)` instead of `regex.exec(str)`?

Comment: `match()` only gives you the matching strings, `exec` gives you match objects with more information available on them (the matching string can be accessed from them as `[0]`). If you want the indexes, you need `exec`.

Comment: @bobince that's not true.  Assuming the regex being used is not global, `String.prototype.match` and `RegExp.prototype.exec` return the same thing.  Tested in chrome, firefox, and ie.  Also Ecma-262 suggests that `match` should use `exec` internally: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.10

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

if the regular expressioin does not include the `g` flag, `str.match()` will return the same result as `RegExp.exec()`

If includes the `g` flag, `str.match()` returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects, Captured groups are not returned

Answer (score 3):

Be careful when using [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function to match a string. The constructed regex object is stateful, i.e. every time you call `.exec()` it affects the [`lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the regex instance. Therefore, you should always reset the `lastIndex` property before using an instance of regex object.

```js
let re,
    findAAs;

re = /AA/;

findAAs = (input) => {
    let match;

    // `re` is cached instance of regex object.
    // Reset `re.lastIndex` every time before using it.

    re.lastIndex = 0;

    while ((match = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
        match.index; // Match index.
        match[0]; // Matching string.
    }
};
```

A tempting alternative is to construct the regex object on every execution. Depending on how resource intensive your task is, this is an option too.

```js
let findAAs;

findAAs = (input) => {
    let match,
        re;

    re = /AA/;

    while ((match = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
        match.index; // Match index.
        match[0]; // Matching string.
    }
};
```

A pragmatic alternative to using `.exec()` is [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
let findAAs,
    re;

re = /AA/;

findAAs = (input) => {
    let match,
        re;

    input.replace(re, (match, index) => {
        match; // Matching string.
        index; // Match index.

        return '';
    });
};
```

The downside of this approach is that it constructs a copy of the subject string.

Whether you should use it or not, depends on how resource intensive your task is. Personally, I like to avoid `while` blocks in my code and therefore prefer the `.replace()` approach.

Comment: > The constructed regex object is stateful. ....

This is true only if you pass `g` flag to regex.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MNXvQ/

I think this is easier to grasp

```
var str = "AAbAAcAAd"
var re = /(AA)/gi;
var t="",cnt=0;
while ((result=re.exec(str))!=null) {
    document.write((cnt++)+":"+result[1]+"<br />")        
}
```

re.lastIndex contains the positions each time

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to bobince's answer is to use the 'lastIndex' property of the regex to get the end index of each match

```
var match, indexes= [];
while (match = r.exec(value)) {
    indexes.push([match.index, r.lastIndex]);
}
```