# Regular Expression to match comma seperated strings in Datatable searching functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatable

I have one string as

```
str="NA,No Therapis delivered,No Therapies Available,None,ATP,CVRT,CVRT x 2,No VT Available,Aborted CVRT,Aborted Defib,Defib,Defib(DBT)"
```

I want a regular expression that would match comma seperated values.
I am using Datatable to show above string in a table.
e.g If i enter 'cvrt' then only 'cvrt' from above strin should be returned.
If I enter 'No Therapis delivered' then only 'No Therapis delivered' should be return.

As I want to do Datatable search, split() method wont work for me.
Only option is to use regular expression.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like so: `(^|,)No Therapies Available(,|$)`. This will look for a particular word, in the case, `No Therapies Available` which is preceded by either by the beginning of the string (`^`) or a comma (`,`) and is succeeded either by another comma (`,`) or the end of the string (`$`).

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178335/all-index-values-of-a-regex-in-javascript) previous SO question, you could use `exec` to match and obtain the location of your search results.

EDIT: The code would look something like so:

```
var searchText = ...;
var searchableText = ...;
var match = [];
var regex = "(^|,)(" + searchText + ")(,|$)/g"
while(match = regex.exec(searchableText)) != null)
{
    alert("Item found at " + match[1].index);
}
```

EDIT 2:

The comma's will be part of the match since those are part of the pattern. My updated answer uses groups to go round this problem, which it would seem is not something you have access to. To go round this problem, you could do something like so:

```
var matchedText =  $('#example').dataTable().fnFilter( "(^|,)" + searchText + "(,|$)/g",columnIndex,true); //this should return a string of the form ',foobar,`
//We then proceed to clean the string by removing leading/trailing commas:
matchedText = matchedText.replace("^,", "");    //Remove leading commas.
matchedText = matchedText.replace(",$", "");    //Remove trailing commas.
alert("Matched Text: " + matchedText);
```

Comment: this is some what I need, but using /(^|,)No Therapies Available(,|$)/ this RegExp, it returns me comma as well. ', No Therapies Available'. I dont want comma to be returned. can we modify above Reg Exp a bit to exclude comma from result ?

Comment: thanks for the Answer.

As I am using datatable filter API to search, above things taken care by the Datatable itself.

What I want to do is someting like following:
$('#example').dataTable().fnFilter( "(^|,)" + searchText + "(,|$)/g",columnIndex,true);

but "(^|,)" + searchText + "(,|$)" returns me ",searchText,"

I dont want commas to be returned in the Result set. Can we modify Regualr Expresion bit?? Thanks

Comment: In DataTable filtering we won't be able to do any post processing as such on matched strings. Thats he reason I want a complete regular expression without leading and trailing commas.

Comment: @user3534391: Then the only other option left would be to pass on the string you are looking for. The *problem* with this is that it will also match substrings, so searching for `foo` would match `foo` and `this is foo abc`.

Comment: @npinti In your second edit where you comment "//Remove trailing commas." shouldn't you be using ",$" instead of ",^"?