# Need a javascript regex to match word without different word both before and after

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match the full word "and" EXCEPT when it appears in idioms that repeat the same word before and after it, like "more and more" or "again and again". I've got this:

```
/(\b\w*\b)\s\band\s(?!\1)/gi
```

Which works, except it also captures the word before "and." I understand you can't do lookbehind regex in JS... Any help appreciated!

**EXAMPLE:**
It should match this **and** plus this **and** but not more and more or less and less.

Comment: can you provide sample input and desired output ?

Comment: I suspect you need something like `s.replace(/\b(\w+)\s+and\s+\1\b|\band\b/gi, function($0,$1) {return $1 ? $1 : "NEW_VALUE"})`.

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible for you to test the opposite, test for the existence of matching pairs and negate the result?

```
/(\b\w+\b)\s\band\s(\1)/gi
```

I did a quick few tests on this at https://regex101.com/r/ZqXbtL/1/tests and it gave me the results I would expect with negation.

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to get the index of matched items and add the length of the word and the space after it to get to index of "and", and so you can use substring or anything like that, i know its not the exact thing you want , but maybe it helps .

the snippet below will get index of second "and"

edit: got help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178335/find-all-matching-regex-patterns-and-index-of-the-match-in-the-string)

```js
var reg = /(\b\w*\b)\s(?=\band\s(?!\1))/g;
var match,indexes = [];
while(match = reg.exec(document.body.innerHTML)){
     indexes.push(match.index + match[0].length);
}

// testing
indexes.forEach(function(element){
    document.body.innerHTML += "<br>\"" +  
    document.body.innerHTML.substr(element,3) + "\" found at  " + element;
});
```

```html
test and test<br>
test and not
```