# remove object from array with just the object's reference

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array of objects called `MyArray` and that a certain function returns a reference for a particular element within that array; something like this:

```
MyArray = [Object1, Object2, ..., Objectn];

function DoWork() {

   var TheObject = GetTheObject(SomeParamter);
}
```

At this point, `TheObject` points to a certain element in the array. Suppose I want to remove this element from `MyArray`, is this possible without having to reloop through the array to get the index of the element?

I'm looking for something like splice that would work with the reference to the element rather than the index of the element.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript

Comment: Writing `TheObject = null` will not clear the object from the array. You have it wrong.

Comment: arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 1);

Comment: If an object should be removed form an array, there is no way around that you or the engine loops over the array. What you can think about is to add an optional parameter to `GetTheObject` that will remove if `true` or keep if `false`.

Comment: @dandavis: you got it

Comment: @acudars: no, it's not a duplicate at all; it's about using splice when you DON'T have the index

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Simply use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
let index = MyArray.indexOf(TheObject);
if(index !== -1) {
  MyArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Keep in mind that if targeting IE < 9 you will need to introduce a polyfill for `indexOf`; you can find [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) in the MDN page.

Comment: where did remove come from?

Comment: Ok, then if it doesn't work in IE8 I'll still accept the answer and will keep it in mind for later even though I have to reloop since IE8 support is a must for now.

Comment: @frenchie: `indexOf` reloops in all browsers anyway. I didn't mean to suggest it somehow determined what the index is out of thin air.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP asked to remove an element by reference and the answer does not do that, it removes it by index.

Comment: @tshm001: It does answer the question. Yes, the actual method call that removes the item requires an index, but the index is calculated automatically based on the reference you pass in. So from the caller's perspective, it effectively removes by reference.

Comment: Jon, the reason this doesn't actually remove by reference is because if you for instance have two separate arrays, Array A and Array B, you cannot simply do ArrayA.indexOf(MyObject). To actually remove the object by reference in actuality would be similar to `delete MyObject` where `delete` knows what array MyObject belongs to, and as requested, actually deletes the object by reference alone.

Comment: @tshm001: Uh, how does multiple arrays make sense in the context of this question, or even any context at all?

Speaking about this question, it clearly says "I want to remove this element from `MyArray`" -- there's no ambiguity there.

In a more general context, how would it be possible for any language or library to offer a "remove this object in whatever container it might be in" unless you explicitly code it to search a given set of containers? It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense if you are able to *delete the object by reference* rather than *delete the object by index*. Of course, you cannot find the index when you do not know the exact array that the object is in. Which is why this code deletes the object by index, rather than reference.

Comment: @tshm001 no, and I give up.

Comment: Think of a nested array of objects, with some containing properties like "children" to contain child arrays of the same kind of objects. This method doesn't remove if you have reference to an object which you don't know the containing array.