# Could you delete an element from a JavaScript and have everything shift accordingly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
delete a[1];
// a  = [1, undefined, 3]
```

Is it possible to delete `2` such that `a` becomes `[1,3]`? So that element 1 becomes 3, element 2 disappears and the length is decreased by one.

Comment: Yes, you want `splice`.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but addressed within [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript/3396127#3396127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
> var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> x.splice(2, 1);
> console.log(x);
[1, 2, 4]
```