# Remove json object in localstorage using js

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

```
[{'id':1,'content':'something'},{'id':2,'content':'something diff'},{'id':3,'content':'something diff'}]
```

by `localStorage.getItem('data')` I got the above json object, but how to delete the id 2 item?

Comment: You decode the JSON string, manipulate the object, and then encode and store it back into localstorage again …

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3396088/218196)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've JSON.parse'd your local storage data into an array, you can remove the second item like you would from any other array- by popping it off.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
// At this point, data is either null or a string value.
// To restore the string to an Array you need to use JSON.parse
if (data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);

  // At this point you can use Array methods like pop or splice to remove objects.
}
// At this point, your Array will only contain the first item.
// If you want to write it back to local storage, you can like so:
// Be sure to use JSON.stringify so it can later be restored with parse.
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: is the last line needed?

Comment: The last line is only needed if you want to write the value back to local storage. I should have specified. :)

Comment: what if I have more than 2 items? .pop will still work?

Comment: @DeanJason: [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3396088/218196)

Comment: You're just asking how to remove items from an array at this point. That's *very* different than the title of your SO question.

Answer (score 0):

This will turn "data" into a javascript object and remove the last item (assuming this is always an array):

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
if (data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   data.pop();
}
```

Comment: .pop remove the last item? I want to match with the id.

Comment: I just noticed @brianvaugn's answer. He beat mine I think. Weird that ours are identical.

Comment: Not that weird! There's only 1 obvious way to parse local storage data and remove the last item from an Array. :)

Comment: Haha, yes. Still funny. I was looking at your code for about 20 seconds trying remember when I added `data` back into `localStorage`. I thought I was looking at my code! :D