# How to remove a task reference in MongoDB user schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user schema with an array of task ObjectId's and I'm trying to figure out how I can go about removing them.

**User Schema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            index: { unique: true }
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
        },
    tasks: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'task'
    }]
})
```

Below is the code I've tried to use but I'm not sure where to go from with what I've done so far.

```
router.delete('/deleteUsersTasks/:_id', async(req, res, next) => {
    User.findById({_id: req.params._id}, (err, user) => {
        User.findByIdAndRemove(tasks: req.body._id)
});
```

Is there a better way to remove the task ObjectId from the tasks array in the user schema or am I just missing something in my route currently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array element in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb)

Comment: Found a solution that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973960/mongoose-remove-object-from-array-based-on-id-cast-error)