# How to delete an object in an array in lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects and I need to delete few of the objects based on conditions. How can I achieve it using lodash map function? 
Ex:

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 0}, {a: 9}, {a: -1}, {a: 'string'}, {a: 5}]
```

I need to delete

```
{a: 0}, {a: -1}, {a: 'string'}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is the logic? Is it by position or key value?

Comment: `arr.filter(({ a }) => a !== 0)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

You can use lodash's remove function to achieve this. It transforms the array in place and return the elements that have been removed

```
var array = [{a: 1}, {a: 0}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}];
var removed = _.remove(array, item => item.a === 0);

console.log(array);
// => [{a: 1}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}]

console.log(removed);
// => [{a: 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

**ES6**

```
const arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 0}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}];

const newArr = _.filter(arr, ({a}) => a !== 0);
```

**ES5**

```
var arr = [{a: 1}, {a: 0}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}];

var newArr = _.filter(arr, function(item) { return item.a !== 0 });
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Answer (score 1):

Other then  _.remove or _.filter you can also use [reject()](https://lodash.com/docs#reject)

```
var array = [{a: 1}, {a: 0}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}];
var result = _.reject(array , ({a}) => a===0 });

console.log(result);//[{a: 1}, {a: 9}, {a: 5}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7z5n5ure/

Answer (score -1):

use this pass arr, key on which you want condition to apply and value is value of key you want to check.

```
function removeElem(arr,key,value){
    return arr.filter(elem=>elem[key]===value)
}
```