# Remove object with no reference from array through a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, find

I made an empty arrayy `playersList = []` that gets filled as the code runs.
To fill it I use: `playersList.push({license, coins: playerCoins})`, which it's working.

I now have something like this:

```js
[
  {
    "license": "a123"
    "coins": 100
  }
  {
    "license": "b123"
    "coins": 200
  }
  {
    "license": "c123"
    "coins": 100
  }   
]
```

I would like to know how can I remove an object through it's license, as they have no reference. I've looked online and tried `index = playersList.findIndex(GetIdentifier(global.source, 'license').toString())` but it says license it's not a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript) or see: [Remove Object from Array using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove the object

```js
const bla = [{
  license: "a123",
  coins: 100
}, {
  license: "b123",
  coins: 200
}, {
  license: "c123",
  coins: 100
}]

const licenseToDelete = 'b123';
console.log(bla.filter(el => el.license !== licenseToDelete))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate the array instead of getting a new one by using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),  you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
const arr = [
  {
    license: 'a123',
    coins: 100
  },
  {
    license: 'b123',
    coins: 200
  },
  {
    license: 'c123',
    coins: 100
  }   
];

const licenseToDelete = 'c123';

// 1 means delete just one element
arr.splice(arr.findIndex(({license}) => license === licenseToDelete), 1);

console.log(arr);
```