# javascript removing items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have "scene" with graphics "objects"...

```
Scene.prototype.objects=new Array();

Scene.prototype.add=function(obj){
  var last=this.objects.length;
  this.objects[last]=obj}

Scene.prototype.remove=function(obj){
  this.objects.splice(obj.id,1)}

Scene.prototype.advance=function(){
  for (var id in this.objects){
    var obj=this.objects[id];
    obj.id=id;
    obj.advance();
  }
}
Scene.prototype.paint=function(context){...}
```

each time creating and deleting many objects. Array.prototype.splice re-index array right? Does anyone know a better technique (adding and removing on javascript Array)?

In my opinion, is another possibility to do that something like

```
Scene.prototype.remove=function(obj){
  delete this.objects[obj.id]; // don,t care about this.objects.length
  delete obj; // not necessary...
}
```

I have not tried it yet...

I need a good book about JavaScript :)

Comment: JavaScript book you'll probably want to read is 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' by Douglas Crockford. It's 150 pages of JS good and bad (yes, there are few these...) parts.

Comment: Drlik: Maybe http://javascriptgarden.info/ is useful?

Comment: Thanks all for reply. I'll use a hash (rather than array, but if delete some_array[index] would work... its seems same). Either way, I'll still have to do sort objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't actually need an array for your objects. You can use another object has hash table:

```
(function() {

    var i = 0;

    Scene.prototype.objects = {};

    Scene.prototype.add = function(obj) {
      var id = i++;
      this.objects[id] = obj;
      obj.id = id;
    };

    Scene.prototype.remove = function(obj){
      if(obj.id in this.objects) {
          delete this.objects[obj.id];
      }
    };

    Scene.prototype.advance=function(){
      for (var id in this.objects){
        var obj=this.objects[id];
        obj.id=id;
        obj.advance();
      }
    };

    Scene.prototype.paint=function(context){...}

}());
```

Comment: @Kooilnc: Based on the OP's code I assumed it has not. If it does, then one can use this one instead of course. Just have to make sure that there are no clashes...

Answer (score 2):

Your delete method wouldn't work, because `objects` is an Array, and obj.id is the id of the object reference stored in an element in that Array. `splice` would be the method to use, but you'll have to know the index of the element in the Array. Maybe you should 'remeber' it this way:

```
Scene.prototype.add=function(obj){
  var last=this.objects.length;
  obj.objectsIndex = last;
  this.objects[last]=obj
}
```

After which you can:

```
Scene.prototype.remove=function(obj){
  this.objects.splice(obj.objectsIndex,1)};
  //reindex the objects within the objects Array
  for (var i=0; i<this.objects.length;i++){
     this.objects[i].objectsIndex = i;
  }
}
```

**Note**: Adding the `objects` Array to the prototype of your `Scene` constructor means it will be the same for all instances (static), is that what you want?

Comment: actually, I do create a scene like this... "function Scene() {this.objects = new Array (); this.views = new Array ();...}" (anyway I have only one scene), but good point... I have no idea about that.

Comment: Well, in that case you don't need (or even want) `Scene.prototype.objects=new Array();` ;~)

Comment: I consider that the splice re-indexed (and re-size) array... as I see it obj.id has been set to corret array index corresponding to obj instance.

Comment: You're right about that. So you'll have to reindex after every remove. Adjusted my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It wouldn't work because of the id. It would work with `this.objects[obj.objectsIndex]` (using the `add` method from my answer), but there are reasons to use `splice` for arrays. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: I tried var x=Array();x[0]="Text";x[1]="Text2";x[2]="Text3";delete x[0];var y=Array();for (var i in x)y.push(x[i]); alert(y.length);//2

Comment: Let's say I extended `Array.prototype` with a `prettyPrint` method, an `each` method and a `frequencies` method, what would the length of `Array y` be in that case?

Comment: Array.prototype.prettyPrint=function(){...};var y=new Array();y.push(1);y.push(2);alert(y.length);//2

Comment: That's because you're using `Array()` to create an array. Try the same using `var x = ["Text","Text2","Text3"]`. Anyway, I don't know what point you're trying to make, but I don't *forbid* you to use `delete` on array elements. Just pointing you to some known contraindications for using it.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that even the "delete method" remove an item from the array (although this is not the best solution, but I think it done faster than the splice-Real remove from array).

Comment: In a last effort: what would you predict to be the length of `x` here? `var x = ["Text","Text2","Text3"]; delete x[0]; delete x[1]; delete x[2]; alert(x.length);`

Comment: 3, so what? I am using "for (var i in array)...", How I wrote in question "delete this.objects[obj.id]; // don,t care about this.objects.length"

Comment: ... ah well, you can always use Resigs method: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather avoid using `new Array()` instead use `[]` (page 114 of book I mentioned in comment - 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' by Douglas Crockford ;)).

What's more, I don't think adding `objects` array to Scene prototype will work as you expect. You probably want to achieve some Object-Oriented structure, which requires some acrobatic skills in JavaScript, as it uses [prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) as it is class-free.

Try something like this:

```js
var Scene = function(initial_objects) {
    this.objects = initial_objects || [];
};

Scene.prototype.add = function(obj) {
    this.objects.push(obj);
};

Scene.prototype.remove_by_index = function(index) {
    this.objects.splice(index, 1);
};

Scene.prototype.remove = function(obj) {
    var index = this.objects.indexOf(obj);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.objects.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Read also this: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html

Comment: You'll want to check `if ( index > -1 )` instead, since `-1` - the return value when the argument is not found in the array - evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Gustav Carlson: thanks for pointing this out, I corrected this.