# Removing an element from an array specifying a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have read this question:

[Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

And it appears that both splice and delete require an index of the element in order to remove, so how can I easily find the index when I have the value?

For example if I have an array that looks like this:

```
["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

and I want to remove test2. The process I am using right now, which I'm hoping isn't the correct way to do it, is using `$.each` checking the value of each element in the array, maintaining a counter through the process (used as the index reference) and if the value is equal to "test2", then I have my index (in form of the counter) and then use splice to remove it.

While the array grows larger, I would imagine this would be a slow process, but what alternatives do I have?

Comment: See `indexOf` for what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function to remove the item, [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) will find it in the array:

**To Find a specific element in the Array:** (*to know which to remove*)

```
var index = array.indexOf('test2');
```

**Full Example:**

```
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
var value_to_remove = 'test2';
array.splice(array.indexOf(value_to_remove), 1);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/Jysku/)**

Comment: He knows that - he even says he is using it in question. What he WANTS to know is how to find the index to USE in `splice`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
array.splice(array.indexOf("test2"), 1);
```

`indexOf` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)):
Returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

Answer (score 2):

You can jQuery's [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) and get rid of your `$.each` loop, and it works cross-browser (unlike Array.indexOf):

```
var index = $.inArray("test2", ["test1", "test2", "test3"]); // 1
```

(I realise your question is not tagged with 'jQuery', but you do mention that you're already using an `$.each` loop).

Answer (score 1):

You find an element by value using [`Array#indexOf`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.14), and then use the resulting index. Note that older browsers may not have it, so you'll want to check to see if it's there and if not add it — [here's some code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) from MDC that does the check and adds the function if it's not there.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n !== n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n !== 0 && n !== (1 / 0) && n !== -(1 / 0)) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Note that if you add things to the `Array` prototype like that, `for..in` loops that assume they'll only see array indexes (that is, [**incorrect**](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) but common `for..in` loops) will start having problems because they'll see the string "indexOf" when they're only expecting to see array indexes, see [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

underscore.js is a really awesome little library with a lot of good utility functions.  In this case #reject would be appropriate.

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reject

(Although the internal method is of course similar to your manual index lookup and slice/splice).