# Removing sections from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have the following array:

```
KHWArray = [{"date":"23 Jan 14","hours":12,"mins":"31","score":22},
           {"date":"23 Jan 14","hours":12,"mins":"36","score":22},
           {"date":"23 Jan 14","hours":12,"mins":"44","score":22}
           ]
```

How can I go about deleting the hours and mins sections from all arrays so I am just left with date and score.

I have looked into splicing and delete but can't seem to make this work

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015512/removing-an-element-from-an-array-specifying-a-value-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array elements are objects, not arrays and there's no built-in function to slice objects. It's easy to write though:

```
function removeKeys(obj, keys) {
    keys.forEach(function(key) { delete obj[key] });
    return obj
}
```

and then

```
KHWArray = KHWArray.map(function(elem) {
    return removeKeys(elem, ['hours', 'mins'])    
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZDaX/

Comment: Note: The `map` method does not exist in older browsers, for example IE8.

Answer (score 2):

`map` seems your best bet:

```
var result = KHWArray.map(function(elt) {
  return {date: elt.date, score: elt.score};
});
```

As an alternative use the versatile `reduce`:

```
var result = KHWArray.reduce(function(target, elt) {
  target.push({date: elt.date, score: elt.score});
  return target;
}, []);
```

Basically pass an empty array as the second argument; it will be referenced as *target* inside the handler. Push an object that fits your needs and return your target.

Caution: `map` and `reduce` are both part of the *ECMAScript 5th edition*. Ensure your targeted browsers support it (or provide a *shim*).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to delete properties from an object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < KHWArray.length; i++) {
  delete KHWArray[i].hours;
  delete KHWArray[i].mins;
}
```