# javascript splicing array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object and I'm looking to remove an element. However, the splice method seems to return the element removed, not the array without the element I wanted to remove.

This is what I have

```
var TheArray = TheObject.Array;
TheArray = TheArray.splice(TheIndex, 1); //TheIndex is the index of the element I want to remove
TheObject.Array = TheArrray;
```

When I debug and run this code, TheObject.Array contains the element I wanted to remove.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting the value of `TheArray` to that of the item you are removing.

Rewrite your code like this:

```
var TheArray = TheObject.Array;
TheArray.splice(TheIndex, 1); //TheIndex is the index of the element I want to remove
TheObject.Array = TheArrray;
```

Comment: Those three lines of code can be replaced with `TheObject.Array.splice(TheIndex,1)`.

Comment: Indeed they can but I wanted to keep the solution as simple as possible to understand. The asker should now know not to bother with the TheArray= part of his code. He can then work out the rest himself. :)

Answer (score 16):

`splice` returns the removed element, but modifies the element on which it was called.  So in your example, `TheArray` is updated in place, and should no longer contain the removed element.

A more concrete, simplified example of how to use `splice` is as follows:

```
var myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var elem = myArr.splice(2, 1);
// elem  => ["c"]
// myArr => ["a", "b", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

do an alert on your array to make sure the array is correct, also you may need to do a parseInt() around your variable (ie TheArray = TheArray.splice(parseInt(TheIndex), 1);) to make sure it's set to be an integer and not a string :)

i hope this helps

Comment: Then at least use `parseInt(..., 10)`.