# Deleting an element from JS associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

How is this done?

If I have the following array defined:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr[id1] = {prop1: prop1Value, prop2:prop2Value};
myArr[id2] = {prop1: prop1Value, prop2:prop2Value};
//etc
```

I wish to delete myArr[id1]

Comment: Dear Patricia, it's not a duplicate. No answer in the question above answers my question. If you think otherwise, it would be great if you posted some code that does. Regards.

Comment: Please note that this is an associative array so it lacks splice(), hence the "duplicate" question doesn't actually answer this one. Please actually READ the question before clicking to close.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean that the numerical indices after the deleted element aren't updated... in which case you'll need to use splice:

```
myArr.splice(id1, 1);
```

Comment: no splice() on associative arrays in JS

Comment: @sarsnake Because associative arrays are just objects, and the only way to delete a property of an object is to use `delete`: `delete myArr[id1];`. The reason `myArr[id1]` still returns `undefined` is because that's what happens when you check a property that doesn't exist: `myArr.fippetyFloppityFloo` also returns `undefined`...