# How to mantain current active sockets in socket.io + node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm starting to learn socket.io and node.js I'm trying to do some pretty basic stuff (or so I think) but I'm unable to do.

Here is my node app:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);
var clients = [];

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clients[socket.id] = true;
    socket.broadcast.emit('conection', { id: clients});
});
```

I want to store connected clients and then, onConnection send them all clients connected. The point is, I don't know how to properly use the arrays on JavaScript because using `clients.push(socket.id)` functions well BUT then, I won't be able to `pop` it a `socket.id` once a client disconnect without looping through the array, right?

Even if there is a method to obtain the current opened sockets, I want to do it in this way because I won't use the application with current socket sessions but with other thing.

I know it's a really noob question so, please, bear with me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put the socket ids in the array like you did the first time, and on disconnect remove the socket.id of the disconnected client. **You don't need to loop thorough an array to delete an element**, you can achieve that using array.indexOf(element) to determine the position of the element and array.splice(position, 1) to delete that element:

```
function deleteFromArray(my_array, element) {
  position = my_array.indexOf(element);
  my_array.splice(position, 1);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  clients.push(socket.id);
  socket.broadcast.emit('conection', { id: clients});
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    deleteFromArray(clients, socket.id);
  });
});
```

Resources:

[Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: Thank you very much @alessioalex it's working out and I've learned something new :)

Comment: Glad to help, by the way you can also upvote an accepted answer.