# Javascript swap array element to another index and removing the old index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, indexing, swap

Is it possible to swap a reference of an object that an array element contains to another index and remove/delete the old index.

Example:
I have an array of OBJECTS with indexes A, B, C, D.

Now I want to create a new array element with index F and assign it the reference of an object that index B contains.  After that, I want to remove B from the array so that only A, C, D, E remains.

What I basically want to do is copy the reference of an object that index B contains and copy it to E.

I have tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
this.cache['A'] = new Orange(1);
this.cache['B'] = new Orange(2);
this.cache['C'] = new Orange(3);
this.cache['D'] = new Orange(4);

// I want to pass the reference B contains
// and assign it to F (like something you can do in C++)
this.cache['E'] = this.cache['B'];  

// First attempt
// length of array is 5 (cache['B'] just has value of undefined)
delete this.cache['B'];

// Second attempt
// the reference to object Orange was deleted in both B and E
this.cache.splice('B', 1);
```

I don't want to create a new object and reassign the values, because there are many references and bindings to the objects, so doing a deep copy would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why the "splice" method is not the solution.

Look at my sample code. I'm using splice there and no any references is lost...

```
function Oo(s) {
    this._s = s;
}

Oo.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "-" + this._s+"-";
}

var a = [];
a.push(new Oo('x'));
a.push(new Oo('y'));
a.push(new Oo('z'));

a[3] = a[1];
alert(a);  // -x-,-y-,-z-,-y-

a[3]._s = 'XX'; // let's change the newly added item
alert(a); // -x-,-XX-,-z-,-XX- <- 3 and 1 points to the same object!

a.splice(1, 1); // remove one element, starting from index = 1
alert(a); // -x-,-z-,-XX-
```

Comment: I was trying to access the newly created element by the wrong index (a[3] in your case).  After an array element has been sliced, all the indices are shifted, so delete index "1" will shit indices "2" to "1" and "3" to "2".  I was trying to work with an array like an associative array which was why it had problems.

Answer (score 0):

To unset an object property you can use the "delete" operator. For example:

```
var f ={
    test1: "fire",
    test2: "water"
}
console.log(f.test2)
//Output water
delete f.test2;
console.log(f.test2)
//Output undefined
```

To resolve your overall problem you could use something similar to.

```
this.cache['A'] = new Orange(1);
this.cache['B'] = new Orange(2);
this.cache['C'] = new Orange(3);
this.cache['D'] = new Orange(4);
this.cache['E'] = this.cache['B'];
delete this.cache['B'];
```

Comment: Your "resolved" code is what is stated in the question itself. Not able to understand the difference!

Comment: Having read over it I can say there is no real difference; it just so happens that the op posted answer to his own question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the object reference is no more with E?

This code:

```
var cache = {};
cache['B'] = new Object( {"hello": "world"} );
cache['E'] = cache['B'];
delete cache['B'];
```

Now cache['E'] still contains the object, that was assigned to cache['B'].

```
> cache['E'].hello
"world"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following sufficient?

```
var myArray= ['a','b','c','d'];
myArray[4] = myArray[1];
myArray.splice(1,1)
var stuff = myArray.join("");
document.write(stuff)
```

Result: acdb

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using object not array. There is no property `length` for object in Javascript.

As array. Here even if it is declared as array, values are not added to the array ( like in php etc. ) . Instead added as properties. So length will be always zero.

```
this.cache = [];
this.cache['A'] = 1;
this.cache['B'] = 2;
this.cache['C'] = 3;
this.cache['D'] = 4;
this.cache['E'] = this.cache['B'];
delete this.cache['B'];
console.log(this.cache['B'], this.cache.length, this.cache.hasOwnProperty('B'));
```

As you can see in the above example `this.cache` is not used as an array. So you can create and object.

```
this.cache = {};
this.cache['A'] = 1;
this.cache['B'] = 2;
this.cache['C'] = 3;
this.cache['D'] = 4;
this.cache['E'] = this.cache['B'];
delete this.cache['B'];
console.log(this.cache['B'], this.cache.length, this.cache.hasOwnProperty('B'));
```

In both cases `hasOwnProperty('B')` will return false. If the object has the property `B`, `hasOwnProperty` will return true.  Your first method should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/diode/hfLJz/1/

.