# Arrays not unset when values are removed - or best way to get count of an array?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript has some funny quirks here and there. Consider this quirk, ripped from [this awesome post](http://dublintech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/javascript-language-z-cheat-sheet.html) (thanks to M. Staveley for sharing this):

```
var colours = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
// is red really in the array?
console.log(colours.indexOf('red') > -1);  // outputs true. 
// remove red, it's going out of fashion!
delete colours[colours.indexOf('red')];
console.log(colours.indexOf('red') > -1);  // outputs false
console.log(colours.length) // length is still three, remember it's javascript!
```

Last line is what bugs me. This quirk has the best of my curiosity, what's an elegant way to get access of real count of `colours`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `delete`

You should use one of the [native array functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp), like `splice` or `shift`

```
colours.shift();
console.log(colours.length);
```

or

```
colours.splice(colours.indexOf('red'), 1);
console.log(colours.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a misuse of Javascript arrays really, so while there is a workaround (use `for...in` and count the number of properties whose names are numbers) you would certainly not call it elegant ([see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/Bm4Yc/)).

Don't use `delete` and don't manually assign indexes to elements (`var colors = []; colors[1000] = 'red';`); it's not how arrays are meant to be used.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` will only delete the element's reference. It won't update the array's logic, and there's no elegant way to get the real count of variables in such a broken array (see [Jon's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10218869/1139697)). So use `shift`, `pop`, `splice` or `var newarray = oldarray.slice`.

See also:

- [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

`delete` just sets the value to `undefined`, it doesn't remove it from the array.

```
delete colours[colours.indexOf('red')];
```

Your array now looks like this:

```
[undefined, 'green', 'blue']
```

As, you can see, the length is still 3.  To remove a value from an array, you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
colours.splice(colours.indexOf('red'), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `delete` to remove items in an array but leaves "holes" in the array. it deletes the value but not it's "space", making the array still have the same length.

to remove a value as well as the space in that array, use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
array.splice(colours.indexOf('red'),1); //remove 1 item starting from index
```

Comment: Do you know where this is defined in the spec? Looking at the [section on `delete`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.7), I can't find anything about the behaviour as applied to an array.

Comment: @JamesAllardice a [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/575527) also mentions this. delete makes the item `undefined`. since is still a value, it retains the space, it does not change the array length. try it out.

Comment: I know that this is what happens, but I am asking why does it happen? Is this behaviour defined in the spec? That answer just demonstrates the same behaviour as yours.

Comment: @JamesAllardice i don't really read specs. I just know that it's the way to to it though.

Comment: Fair enough. I know it is the way to do it, and I have never used `delete` with an array, but now the question has been asked I just like to find out exactly what's going on under the hood.