# How can I remove an element from an array with javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting an element in an array like this:

```
dialogs[id] = $.modal({
    title: "Admin",
    closeButton: true,
    content: content,
    width: false,
    resizeOnLoad: true,
    buttons: {
        'Close': function (win) {
            win.closeModal();
        }
    }
}).find('form') // Attach logic on forms
.submit(formSubmitHandler)
.end();
```

Later on I check if exists like this:

```
if (!dialogs[id]) {
    loadAndShowDialog(id, link, url);
}
```

How can I remove the `id` record from the dialogs array? Is there something like a `dialogs[id].Remove()` ?

Comment: You will need to use `splice()`, see first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command is : (set it to undefined)

```
delete dialogs[id];
```

if you want to completely remove : use `splice`.

### edit

I mistakely thought that its is an object property which you want to remove ( delete will be fine here - and only solution)

howevert - you have an Array and the correct answer is to use `splice`.

Comment: Be aware that `delete` does not actually *remove* the element but rather replaces it with `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this [tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/array). It explains really well how to play with arrays in javascript.

The `delete` method doesn't *delete* an element, it just replaces it with `undefined`. To delete elements from an array, you need [`splice`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/array#method-splice).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), here is how to use it:

```
array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])
```

So, you need the `index` where you want to start deleting, and `howMany` is the number of elements you want to delete.

For your case, it'd be:

```
dialogs.splice( dialogs.indexOf( id ), 1 )
```

Note the use of `indexOf` to find out the index of the `id` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
delete dialogd[id]; //will not remove element, will set it to undefined
```

or

```
dialogs.splice(id,1); //will not work in case of non-numeric indices
```

Choose whichever one is appropriate. I prefer the second.

Answer (score 0):

when removing an item from an array, use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
dialogs.splice(id,1); //remove "1" item starting from index "id"
```

note that this removes the item, and changes the array length. so in an array of 3, if i spliced this way, the array will now have a length of 2.

using `delete` will not affect the array, but leave that location `undefined`. it's like "unsetting" or "leaving a hole" in that location.

```
delete dialogs[id];  //value at index "id" is now undefined
```