# JavaScript array slice versus delete

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Is there any reason why one should be used over the other?

e.g.

```
var arData=['a','b','c'];
arData.slice(1,1);//removes 'b'

var arData=['a','b','c'];
delete arData[1];//removes 'b'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`delete` leaves you with `[ 'a', undefined, 'c' ]`

`splice` leaves you with `[ 'a', 'c' ]`

`slice` doesn't do anything to the original array :)  But it returns `[ 'b' ]` in your code

Answer (score 6):

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements) only makes that certain location of the array `undefined` but the array still contains 3 items: `['a',undefined,'c']`

the other way to do it is [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and not [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). splice totally removes that item and it's location, so you end up with `['a','c']`