# How to remove a node from a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

So...I have this array:

```
val['an_element'][0]['another_element'][2]['text']
```

I want to get rid of the entire "2" node.

Now...I THOUGHT the way to do this would be:

```
delete val['an_element'][0]['another_element'][2];
```

BUT...it doesn't actually drop the element, but simply empties it out.

I also tried:

```
val['an_element'][0]['another_element'][2] = null;
```

...but that just resulted in my console log nearly bleeding it was so red with errors.

Basically, i want that [2] node to NO LONGER EXIST. Basically, I want it to NOT BE FOUND AT ALL.

What do I do??? And I know the ".splice" method will NOT actually modify the original array, so please don't suggest it. :)

Comment: splice is a Mutator function, it will change the original array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: So your array actually is `val['an_element'][0]['another_element']`, containing objects with `text` properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript array slice versus delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325026/javascript-array-slice-versus-delete), and notice the difference between `slice` and `splice`!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Answer (score 3):

The `splice` method will, in fact, modify the array. Just try:

```
val['an_element'][0]['another_element'].splice(2, 1);
```

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements.
>   ...
>   If you specify a different number of elements to insert than the number you're removing, the array will have a different length at the end of the call.