# How to avoid having undefined members in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The problem is strange: I removed from Array (association) a few elements by splice function,  after this I added a few elements and suddenly there were "underfined" elements. Below there is the log (after '//' this my comment to this):

```
// adding first element; array length = 1
["asdasdasd"] microblog.js:48

// adding second element; array length = 2
["asdasdasd", "asdasdasd"] microblog.js:48 

// adding third element;  array length = 3
["asdasdasd", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasdqwe"] microblog.js:48 

// removing second element;  array length = 2
["asdasdasd", "asdasdasdqwe"] microblog.js:66 

// removing third element; array length = 1
["asdasdasdqwe"] microblog.js:66

// adding new element;  array length = 4
["asdasdasdqwe", undefined × 2, "asdasdqwrevcvxzvvxwfrqeqwewq"]
```

And this is how I add an element:

```
(...)
this.list[currId] = text;
(...)
```

And this is how I remove an element

```
(...)
this.list.splice(currId, 1);
(...)
```

How to avoid this undefined elements?

Comment: That occurs because you incorrectly remove elements. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: I read this before to find the best way to remove elements. So I decided to use "splice", but there is no about adding element after removing or I can't see it. If you could, expain what I do wrong? As you can see during removing I can't detect the problem, only when an element is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either **A**) -> You're using current element to track the position to next add to, and never decreasing it:

```
var arr = []
for (var currId = 0; currId < 4; currId++) {
    arr[currId] = currID
}
//arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.splice(1, 3); // arr = [1]
// if currID is still 3
arr[currId] = "text"; // now arr = [1, undefined, undefined, "text"]
```

in which case you need to decrease currId when you remove items to add them in the very next place.

Or **B**) -> just use `Array.push()`

```
var arr = []
for (var currId = 0; currId < 4; currId++) {
    arr.push(currId);
}
//arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.splice(1, 3); // arr = [1]
arr.push("text"); // now arr = [1, "text"]
```

**B** is a much better solution, if just adding the element to the end of the array is what you wanted.

EDIT: Since you want to maintain the "currID" as the next position in the Array to place an item at, I assume whenever you do this,

```
this.list[currId] = text;
```

you follow it with this:

```
currId++;
```

If that is correct, then the opposite thing to do would be to decrease it when you splice objects out of the Array e.g:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
currId = 4 // The next position to add at is 4.
removeCount = 3;
arr.splice(1, removeCount); // arr = [1]
currId -= removeCount;
```

But frankly, this is an awful way to do this. Please give some more information so that we can help you find a better way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay B is good option, but I what to use array as hash table. I need to know the key of element, so I can't use push.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using an object rather than an array? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What's your `currId` for?

When adding an element (to the end), you should do this:

```
this.list.push(text)
```

or

```
this.list[this.list.length] = text
```

and modify the element by index.

Comment: currId is interger, but I use it as key.