# Delete an object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

So, in javascript, I have this set up:

```
global.menu = [{
   name: item1,
   price: price1,
   message: message1
},
{
   name: item2,
   price: price2,
   message: message2
},
{
   name: item3,
   price: price3,
   message: message3
}];
```

And my question is pretty simple, but how would I delete an object from this array?
To select an object, I'm using this command:

```
global.HandleMenu = function (b) {
    var c = menu.filter(function (d) {
        return d.name == b;
    });
    c.forEach(function (d) {
        Say(d.message);
    });
};
```

So yeah. Can I just add delete d;, or d.remove() inside the forEach function? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use filter and re-assign

```
global.menu = global.menu.filter(function(a){ return a.item != "be delete" };
```

Comment: This looks like it would delete the entire array, whereas I would only need to delete the object with selected name.

Comment: delete one item is equal to select other item without delete item. it's simple solution using list

Comment: OHHHHHH. Derp. I just actually LOOKED at the code, thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for. Derp derp derp.

Comment: If there are any other references to the original `global.menu` Array, they'll remain unmodified.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the name of the item you want to delete is in a variable called `name`, something like

```
for (var i = 0; i = global.menu.length - 1; i--) {
   var current = global.menu[i];
   if (current.name === name) global.menu.splice(i, 1);
}
```

should work.  Note I'm not testing for nulls; but this is the general idea.

Comment: This would work but how do I find the index of the object, with only the name of the object given?

Comment: this would work, but I like the above answer better, it's simpler and to the point. Thanks though!

Comment: @dalton, no problem.  this is just an alternative.  Note that my implementation modifies the actual array, filter creates a new array.

Comment: Yes, but it all works out if you're replacing the old array with the new array, doesn't it?

Comment: @DaltonGore: Not if there are other references to the original Array. They'll still be holding on to the old one. Probably safer to modify the original unless you can absolutely guarantee that no other code keeps a reference to `global.menu`.

Comment: am not i am, ah good point.  excellent point in fact