# how to remove an array item in Global.JSON parse object???  titanium mobile?

Tags: arrays, json, mobile, titanium, push

how to remove an array item in Global.JSON parse object???

Answer (score 0):

When you parse a JSON string to a JavaScript object, it becomes a JavaScript object, and the JSON string becomes irrelevant. So the heart of your question is "how do I remove an item from an array?"

For that, you either delete or splice out the item you no longer want. The usage and difference of these has been answered elsewhere:
[Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)