# jQuery remove item from serialized array

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I'm trying to figure out how to remove item from serializedArray by using the index.
The following scenario:

```
[ 
    { 'name' : 'item1', 'value' : '1' }, 
    { 'name' : 'item2', 'value' : '2' }, 
    { 'name' : 'item3', 'value' : 3 } 
]
```

Now I would like to remove 'item2' - I can use the following function - but not sure how to remove it - is there some sort of unset() method or something like this:?

```
serializeRemove : function(thisArray, thisName) {
    "use strict";
    $.each(thisArray, function(index, item) {
        if (item.name == thisName) {
            // what to do here ?        
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does this serialzed array come from? could you exclude it from the collection that creates this serialized array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use vanilla JS' [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like this:

```
serializeRemove : function(thisArray, thisName) {
    "use strict";
    return thisArray.filter( function( item ) {
               return item.name != thisName;
           });
}
```

`filter()`  uses the callback function to test each element of the array. If the function returns `true` the element will be in the result. If it returns `false`, the element will be dropped.

`filter()` is supported by all major browsers and IE9+.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `delete` which is [a standard JavaScript operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete): http://jsfiddle.net/2NsUD/

```
var array = [ 
    { 'name' : 'item1', 'value' : '1' }, 
    { 'name' : 'item2', 'value' : '2' }, 
    { 'name' : 'item3', 'value' : 3 } 
];

var arrayClean = function(thisArray, thisName) {
    "use strict";
    $.each(thisArray, function(index, item) {
        if (item.name == thisName) {
            delete thisArray[index];      
        }
    });
}

console.log(array);
arrayClean(array, 'item3');
console.log(array);​
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the length of array remains unaffected -- which may not be desired.

Comment: Good point -- there are other options that will decrease the length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: "delete array[index];"   should be  "delete thisArray[index]; " to make this work