# remove data from post before ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that I am posting via JQuery ajax function.
The flow of the application is as follows:

1. The user fills out the form and submits it
2. When the form is posted the data is saved in a temporary array
3. If the form was already submitted I want to only send the data that has been changed in the new submission

The form fields I want to compare:

```
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd2; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd3; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd4; ?>]" type="text">
```

I want to post only the values of the inputs that have changed.

The code to compare the previous form submission with the current one (the previous submission is saved in the array `tmpArray`:

```
var fields = $('.option').serializeArray();
var n = 0;
jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
     if(field.value === tmpArray[n]){
         console.log(field.value+" : "+tmpArray[n]+ " TRUE");
     } else {
         console.log(field.value+" : "+tmpArray[n]+ " FALSE");
     }
    n++;
});
```

The ajax function to submit the form:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    url: '/Controller/'+action,
    success: function(response) {
        jQuery('#resultField').val(response);
    },
    data: jQuery('form').serialize()
});
```

Is there anyway (or a better way) to remove the values from the `('form').serialize()` result in the each() loop if they match the value in the `tmpArray`?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please check following post, it has possible answer to your question.

[jQuery remove item from serialized array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687652/jquery-remove-item-from-serialized-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could try,

```
var tempArray=[];


    var tempArrayString = JSON.stringify(tempArray);
    var values = $('.option').serializeArray();
    values = values.filter(function(field){
        return tempArrayString.indexOf(JSON.stringify(field))==-1;
    });    
    if(values.length>0){
        tempArray = values;//or something
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33dh2/