# Arraylist, Linkedlist in Javascript Window app store Metro style?

Tags: javascript, window, microsoft-metro

I am writing a game for the Windows App store that will use HTML5 and Javascript.

Are there any implementations of ArrayList or LinkedList for this platform?  If so could someone give me an example how to use it?

Comment: are you looking for 1-1 correspondence with the .NET classes?  You probably won't find that, but the JavaScript Array should suffice and you can find a few sample JavaScript classes implementing a linked-list structure.  Both are data structures that can be built without too much trouble in JavaScript (and most languages)

Comment: I know we can implement a linked-list structure in JS. But my problem is release memory. JS has garbage collection but if I use an Array or implement linked-list, it does not auto release memory. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @goose: Of course JS garbage collection also works with arrays. Why don't you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript `Array` does not have a fixed length and thus can be used like an `ArrayList`. You just have to use [the right methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Methods):

- `arrayList.Add(element)` = `array.push(element)`
  Adds an element to the end of the array. The push/pop naming works like a queue: add/remove at the end.
- `arrayList.AddRange(collection)` = `array.push(element1, element2, ...)`
  Adds multiple elements to the end of the array. Like many other `Array` methods, `push` can take a variable number of elements to append.
- `arrayList.RemoveRange(index, count)` = `array.splice(index, count)`
  The name is a bit less obvious. `splice` removes the given number of elements (`count`) at `index`.
- `arrayList.RemoveAt(index)` = `array.splice(index, 1)`:
  Passing `1` as `count` to `splice` removes just one element.
- `arrayList.Insert(index, x)` = `array.splice(index, 0, element)`
  `splice` also takes a variable number of elements to insert at the index after removing the given number of elements. By removing no elements (passing `0` as `count`), you can use it to simply insert new elements.

All of these methods correctly adjust the length of the array and shift elements around, as opposed to `delete array[index]`. `delete` simply removes *properties* from an *object* and does not treat arrays differently, so you're left with a "gap".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem! All I want that I can release memory in array. It can be done by using "delete" keyword for each element of array, but array's length is not reduced.

And about Array List in JavaScript, I think the current build-in array is fine. No need to implement more.

Comment: No, you never use `delete` to [remove array items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/1048572)