# setMap(null) on Map Marker does not truly destroy the marker (jquery-ui-map)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-map

Here's the problem:

I want to remove all map markers from the map when they go out of the viewport.  I have the code that checks for their position, then runs setMap(null) on the marker.  The marker disappears.  I then set the marker itself to null to destroy it, per the Google Maps documentation.

The problem is that jquery-maps-ui's function for retrieving the map markers *still* includes the deleted markers!

```
function cleanUpMarkers(map) {
        console.log("$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers').length = " +  $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers').length);
        $.each($('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers'), function (i, marker) {
            if (!map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
                console.log(marker.internalId);
                marker.setMap(null);
                marker = null;
                delete marker;


                //console.log(marker.internalId);

            }
        });
        console.log("$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers').length = " + $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers').length);

    }
```

How can I *truly* delete the marker so that **$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers')** doesn't return the deleted markers?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/2110460 for deleting an array element, which is what markers are essentially.

Comment: Brilliant!  Post that as an answer, rather than a comment so I can accept it!

Thanks, Rafe, it works.  I just had to change my for loop to use an index instead of using the jquery .each function.