# Script debugger confirms intended conditional check between JSON key and string, however I am getting an undesired result?

Tags: javascript, json

I am looking to modify the output table I am getting from this handy [Json-to-HTML-Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table) script I stumbled upon here on SO. There is a point (line 86) where *json-to-table.js* passes a JSON object and generates array keys to be used as table headers. Optionally, this `array_key` function can generate only one key for a specified `search_value` parameter passed. I however [attempted] to modify it so that ALL array keys that did NOT match the `search_value` would be returned. Here is the function after my changes:

```
function array_keys(input, search_value, argStrict)
{
    var search = typeof search_value !== 'undefined', tmp_arr = [], strict = !!argStrict, include = '', key = '';

    if (input && typeof input === 'object' && input.change_key_case) { // Duck-type check for our own array()-created PHPJS_Array
        return input.keys(search_value, argStrict);
    }

    for (key in input)
    {
        if (input.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            include = false;
            if (search)
            {
                if (strict && input[key] == search_value)
                    include = false;
                else if (input[key] == search_value)
                    include = false;
                else
                    include = true;
            } 
            if (include)
                tmp_arr[tmp_arr.length] = key;
        }
    }
    return tmp_arr;
}
```

Now, the reason I did this is because I want my generated table to not include a specific column from my JSON object:

```
{
    "examItemCategories": [
        {
            "catgoryName": "01-Normal processes",
            "catgoryPath": "General Area\\01-Normal processes",
            "numberOfItems": 2,
            "percentage": "6.06"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given that I can not modify the original JSON obj passed, I was determining whether or not to attempt to modify the table post creation (e.g. remove column), or during. After looking at the `array_keys` function, I felt I could easily invert the conditional checking for the `search_value`.

I now call `array_keys(parsedJson[0], 'catgoryPath');` from json-to-table script. (Yes, *catgoryPath* is the correctly spelled name haha). Then I set a break point at the for loop within `array_keys` function to follow it through in Firebug.

First iteration: `catgoryName` is added to `tmp_arr`, 2nd iteration: `catgoryPath` is added to `tmp_arr`...and continues through 3rd and 4th iterations. I do not want`catgoryPath` added.

Looking at script debugger, on the 2nd iteration, whether or not `catgoryPath` gets added comes down to the conditional: `else if (input[key] == search_value)` line. The thing is, on the respective iteration both `key` and `search_value` variables equal "catgoryPath" according to Firebug. So therefore, `include = false;` should fire correct?

Any help is appreciated, apologies for the length and liberal usage of inline code.

Comment: @imsiso Any ideas? I've tried all types of different setups for the `for(key in input)` loop. Read into equality operators, still nothing is working. Coming from Java I want to .toString() the key or something just to ensure I am comparing the same data types, but therein lies the beauty of the '==' operator in JS.

Comment: @imsiso I actually figured it out! I appreciate the support though. Turns out since JS 1.8.5 there is a built in function to retrieve keys from an object. Didn't have to mess around with that `array_keys` function at all. Simpler code ftw

Comment: your welcome. and as I see in your profile you are very good in computer science and I will get help someday from you.(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `array_keys` function from the json-to-table script, if you are using JS > 1.8.5 you can use [Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

The returned array of keys are then used as table headers under which the table populates with JSON data thanks to the script. Prior to the creation of table, I took my array of table headers and used [array.splice(index, howMany)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of `delete` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)) to preserve my array index values.