# What is the better way to remove the "parent index of" of an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`enter code here`Im making an nodejs application... let me show my question;;

```
//id = dinamic string.. "user1", "user2", "userX"  
usersArray = [];
usersArray[id]["socket"] = socket;
```

When sockets ends, I want to remove [id] from usersArray.. but at this time `id` is not availabe

```
socket.on('end', function () {
    ?........?
    socket.end();
});
```

How to do it?

Comment: You should be using a plain object `{}` instead of an Array. Then have the `socket` store its own `id`, or use a variable if each additional socket is added in a separate function call.

Comment: Ok.. may you show how?

Comment: `usersArray = {};`, but consider changing it to `users` or something else, to prevent confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `socket.id` which works well as an identifier for each socket. Then, you can use an associative array instead of `usersArray`:

```
var usersArray = {};
usersArray[socket.id] = some_user_data;
```

You can then remove this entry using `delete usersArray[socket.id]`.

Comment: [Don't delete elements in an array, splice them out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements).

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Rather than that, I'd just use an Object here. I'd edit to make this clear.

Comment: But I want to use the identifiers from Database... The people can choose any name, At sockets end I dont have the userId, bcouse I didnt check database to see if he should stay

Comment: So make another associative array, and simply set `arr[socket.id] = user_id`, then use it as a lookup whenever needed. On disconnect, clean up both.

Comment: I'd do the opposite though - keep `usersArray[socket.id]` and store the database's `user_id` inside. Node.js code often needs to find the user by "his" socket.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to thisId from inside the socket.on('end') function, you could do something like:

```
socket.on('end', function () {
    usersArray.splice(thisId, 1);
    socket.end();
});
```

Comment: Taking the mention `but at this time all I have is socket data` it might be safe to assume that `thisId` is not available. Luckily you can easily create a second or third event handler within a scope where both the `socket` and `thisId` is available.

Comment: Right there.. Id is not available

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you add the sockets to your `userArray` (which seems to be an `object` rather than an `array` noticing your examples for `id`), you could consider just adding a new callback to the socket when you add it to the array

```
usersArray[someId].socket = socket;

// New callback to just delete the usersArray entry
usersArray[someId].socket.on('end', function() {
   delete usersArray[someId];
});
```

Leave the current `socket.on` untouched:

```
socket.on('end', function () {
    /* No new code here, as the deletion happens
       when the socket is added to usersArray!
     */
    socket.end();
});
```

Comment: [Don't delete elements in an array, splice them out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements).

Comment: @Elliot, see my mention on the array probably not being an array.

Comment: @Roonaan someId is not available at this time

Comment: @Filipe, `someId` must be availabe, as you use it to assign the socket to the `usersArray`. The whole point of this solution, is that you create another `on('end'` in that code block, with the explicit role to only delete the entry in the array. You leave you current `on('end'` untouched.