# JS .indexOf('string') returns -1

Tags: javascript

I have an Array[] `this.unusedInstruments`:

```
[
    { label: 'one'},
    { label: 'two'},
    { label: 'three'}
]
```

and a function: (params getting passed in are verified as being 'one', 'two', or 'three'

```
removeInstrument: function(removedIntrument) {
  var index = this.unusedInstruments.indexOf(removedIntrument);
  delete this.unusedInstruments[index];
},
```

but I am not getting what I expected.   I logged the `index`, and it is always returning `-1` despite the parameter.  I am assuming that it is saying that the index doesn't exist, but I guess that means I don't know how to query the parent Array for the indexed Object.

Comment: is the array you posted `this.unusedInstruments`?

Comment: thats not how `indexOf` works.

Comment: @Daniel Chapman: "indexOf is a string method" - that's not entirely correct. Try `['a'].indexOf('a')` and see

Comment: @DanielA.White ah,   I got the idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array), so i thought it was for any "query" given they use integers, but I guess JS is thinking it of them as strings

Comment: It is a string method and an array method (as of ES5). And also please [don't link to W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as it's an array - you cannot just `delete` its elements, otherwise you'll get a holes with `undefined` value. So you need a bit more intelligent way of doing that:

```
removeInstrument: function(removedInstrument) {
    var len = this.unusedInstruments.length,
        i;

    var remove = function(arr, from) {
        // Based on John Resig's article (MIT Licensed)
        // http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

        var rest = arr.slice(from + 1);
        arr.length = from;
        return arr.push.apply(arr, rest);
    };

    for (i = 0; i < len ; ++i) {
        if (this.unusedInstruments[i].label == removedInstrument) {
            remove(this.unusedInstruments, i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`remove()` function implementation idea is borrowed at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815010/251311

Answer (score 1):

`.indexOf()` will only work if the string is an element of the array you're searching. But in your data, the string is the value of the `label` property of the element, it's not the element itself. You need to write a loop that drills into the objects and compares with the property.

```
removeInstrument: function(removedInstrument) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.unusedInstruments.length; i++) {
        if (this.unusedInstruments[i].label == removedInstrument) {
            delete this.unusedInstruments[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```