# How to delete a specific element from an array of JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving a JSON output from a php file,
with a number of objects like so:

```
[
  { "home_content" : "Nam feugiat sem diam, ut fermentum orci hendrerit sit amet.",
    "home_id" : 2,
    "home_img" : "tech.png",
    "home_title" : "Latest Technologies Development"
  },
  { "home_content" : "לורם לורם",
    "home_id" : 239,
    "home_img" : "http://placehold.it/400",
    "home_title" : "שוק פירות וירקות"
  },
  { "home_content" : "New Item Content",
    "home_id" : 259,
    "home_img" : "http://www.placehold.it/100",
    "home_title" : "New Home Item"
  }
]
```

In my App I want to delete a certain object,
is there a way to recieve its position say by `home_id` ?
or anything that will let me differentiate a certain object from that list

Comment: You have an array of objects, you can iterate through the array, checking the `home_id` of each.

Comment: What is your question, since it looks like you've actually asked two. Do you want to know how to *search* the array for specific object which matches a `home_id`, or do you want to *remove* an object from the array which matches the `home_id`?

Comment: Yes this can easily be done.  Have you tried to implement something and run into problems?

Comment: This isn't JSON! it's a valid javascript array literal, however.

Comment: This should be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is an array of objects, so you can just loop through the array until you find the one with the desired `home_id`:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
    if (array[index].home_id === 2) {
        array.splice(index, 1); // Removes this entry
        break;                  // Exits the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thank you for pointing out that this is an 'array of objects'.
I ended up looping through the array as you showed, but using coffeescript:
    for item, z in $scope.home

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an array (obtained from parsing JSON), so you'll have to find the correct index, and splice it:

```
function delObjWithHomeId(arr, id) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].home_id === id) {
            return arr.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted there is an array of objects. That's an important distinction -- though in javascript, and array **is** a type of object.

An object, as you see, can have alphanumberic property names (indexes, if you will) that correspond to a data element. An array, by contrast, is numerically indexed, starting at 0. It is a lot like an object, but the property names are all numbers, and all in sequential order.

So, **imagine** your data like this:

```
{
0:{ 
home_id: 2
home_title: Latest Technologies Development
home_img: tech.png
home_content: Nam feugiat sem diam, ut fermentum orci hendrerit sit amet.
},
1:{ 
home_id: 239
home_title: שוק פירות וירקות
home_img: http://placehold.it/400
home_content: לורם לורם
},
2:{ 
home_id: 259
home_title: New Home Item
home_img: http://www.placehold.it/100
home_content: New Item Content
}
}
```

You can use a number of methods to manipulate an array, like `push()`, `pop()`, `shift()`. To access a specific one, you usually wind up looping it (unless you already know the correct *index*).

There are several methods to looping an array, `while` being one of the many possible approaches:

```
var i = 0;
while(var oneItem = myArray[i++]){
    if (oneItem.home_id == theItemIdIAmLookingFor) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Documentation**

- Arrays on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- Objects on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
- Array.push on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push
- Loop statements on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Loop_Statements

Comment: If you delete, you just remove property i, but you don't change the length. So it leaves a gap in the array.