# How to remove an array element without splice and without undefined remaining?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to remove an array element at a certain position, without rearranging indexes, and without that position changing to undefined?

I don't think that is possible with delete nor splice?

I need an accurate way to view the length of the array, without rearranging indexes.

I do not want to use splice because i have an object that has specific positions mapped to actual X,Y points of a tabel (Punkt).

UPDATE: actually, knowing if the array element exists out of ONLY undefined values might also help me, is there an easier way then looping through?

```
var keys = Object.keys(racks);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < racks[keys[i]].punkt.length; x++)
    {
        if(racks[keys[i]].punkt[x].y == fullName)
        {
            //delete racks[keys[i]].punkt[x];
            racks[keys[i]].punkt.splice(x,1);
            console.log(keys[i] + " : " + racks[keys[i]].punkt.length); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can, but you can't do it with only one array.

Comment: Why don't you just have a variable called `arraylength` that's incremented each time an element is added to the array but doesn't change when an element is removed.

Comment: Why don't you want use splice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: The length of an array will always be the highest index + 1 (indices are zero based), so no, you can't remove something, keep the index and expect length to be accurate -> http://jsfiddle.net/vLDeA/

Comment: @adeneo: *"The length of an array will always be the highest index + 1"* That depends on what you mean by "highest index." It's entirely possible for `length` to be `7` when there is no entry at index `6`. `var a = []; a.length = 7; console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(6)); // false`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Well, yes! If you specifically set the length property yourself you can set it to anything I suppose, I meant by just adding and removing with the built in methods.

Comment: @adeneo guys; setting length = length-1 might also help, i'm not sure what the exact implications of this are though?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Would be neat if there was something like enumerable = false for arrays?

Comment: @adeneo: You mean like this? http://jsbin.com/IcemuJu/1/edit ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Indeed, as arrays are objects, defineProperty works for those as well, and enumerable is false by default when using that method. Quite clever, didn't think of that.

Comment: What are you guys talking about, you are confusing me :o

Comment: @Faarbhurtz Setting the length manually won't work, the deleted key will still be missing, and the last value will be chopped off. You end up with an array of length = originalLength - 1, but with originalLength - 2 keys. All your options are summarized in T.J. Crowder's answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't think that is possible with delete nor splice?
>
> I need an accurate way to view the length of the array, without rearranging indexes.

Then `delete`, a `hasOwnProperty` or `in` guard when retrieving from the array, and a loop counting the elements (or a separate variable keeping track) is the only way to do it. JavaScript's standard arrays are inherently *sparse* (because they're [not really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), they can have gaps in them where they don't have entries. To create a gap, delete the array entry using `delete`.

Example:

```
// Setup
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
console.log(a.length); // 4

// Using delete
delete a[2];           // Delete the entry containing "c"
console.log(a.length); // Still 4
a.hasOwnProperty(2);   // false

// Using the guard when getting an entry
if (a.hasOwnProperty(2)) { // Or `if (2 in a)`
    // Get and use [2]
}
else {
    // Do whatever it is you want to do when the array doesn't have the entry
}

// Finding out how many it *really* has:
var key;
var count = 0;
for (key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)  &&        // See below
        /^0$|^[1-9]\d*$/.test(key) &&
        key <= 4294967294
        ) {
        ++count;
    }
}
console.log(count);    // 3
```

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/157247) for the details behind that `if` in the loop. If you never put non-element properties on the array, you can skip the second and third parts of that `if`.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly.

```
    var delrow = window.event.srcElement;
    while ((delrow = delrow.parentElement) && delrow.tagName != "TR");
    delrow.parentElement.removeChild(delrow);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var punten = racks[keys[i]].punkt.length;
                            if(racks[keys[i]].punkt[x].y == fullName)
                            {
                                delete racks[keys[i]].punkt[x];
                                punten--;
                            }

                            if(punten==0)
                            {
                                console.log("Could have removed device: " + keys[i]);
                            }
```