# javascript pass argument to object.keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object that contains things i'm looking for:

### Exclusions

1: Object [ ID: "38433" , Location: "Central"]
  2: Object [ ID: "43434" , Location: "West"]

and I have a Object called **Schools** that contains the set of all things:
I am using the `Object.keys()` method to loop through the object, but I need to pass in what Location to search to search in say Central, or West,etc. If I try to do something like (Schools.District.location) I get an error. How do i pass in the correct argument to my `object.keys` function?

part2: What is the correct way to remove an element from that array. So i would need to remove Location[15] if say the ID's match.

Code:

```
$.each(Exclusions , function (index, value) {

var location = value.Location;  //gives me Central, West, East
var ID = value.ID;

Object.keys(Schools.District.{{pass in location}}).forEach(function (key) {

 //each location is an array of schools so i need to scan each for the matching ID


  for (var i=0; i < {{get length of location array}}.length; i++) {

      if(location[i][ID] == ID) 
       {
          location.slice();  //not sure about this
       }

    }


});
```

Comment: `Schools.District[location]` should work. http://jsfiddle.net/3aEK6/

Comment: and on deleting: **Array**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements  **Object.property:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: good answer @will to deleting a property on an object, thanks

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `objects.key` certainly ? why dont you use a `for in` ?

```
var result = [];
for (i in YOUR_OBJECT)
{
    if(YOUR_OBJECT[i].location == "what you want") result.push(YOUR_OBJECT[i]);
}
```

i guess you can not remove property you want probably, but you can set that to `null`, and at the end, get those property that its not `null`

EDIT:
to delete a property on YOUR_OBJECT: (i is a key iterator)

```
delete YOUR_OBJECT[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use @am1r_5h's answer above. For each iteration, `i` (I prefer to use `key` though) is a proper key. (In the case of an array, an integer index.) Collecting the keys to use later is not idiomatic JavaScript.
2. Use the `splice` method to delete from an array. It completely deletes the element and replaces it with nothing so that the new length of the array is `original_length - 1`. Using `delete` and passing the element index will replace the element with `undefined` while the length of the array remains the same. Here's the docs for `Array.prototype.slice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: are you sure i read that Object.keys() is the correct way to extract information in your array as it does not return prototype data.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In the `for` loop, you could add this condition ```if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // code goes here ...
}
```
to ensure that you're not messing with prototype data.

Comment: @Yaw but i think @Edward has an object which to fill that properties by some locations and use that object as a dictionary, not an array... to deleting property on an object i guess there is no way but in an array using `.splice` like @Yaw said

Comment: good answer @will to deleting a property on an object, thanks

Comment: @am1r_5h `delete obj[key]`. That's how to delete a key-value pair from a JavaScript object