# How to add and remove elements of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to maintain a list of things in javascript. This seems to be a non trivial problem in this language...

```
var things = []

// for adding:
things[things.length] = thing

// for removing:
delete (things[things.indexOf(thing)])
```

This kinda works, but I fear the adding is a bug. When a thing that is not at the end of the array gets removed, a following add operation will overwrite an existing element, right? Because length is the number of elements.

How to do the adding correctly? Or is there a better way to do this with plain javascript (no JQuery)?

Comment: Have a read through all of the [available `Array.prototype` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You will find better ways to achieve both of those things.

Comment: [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the referenced question as it asks about adding and removing elements from an array.

Comment: @JamesAllardice I didn't, sorry. All I found were weird solutions like the one I posted, or someone was even setting elements to 0 for "removing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). With push, you don't have to keep track of your last inserted index. Also, with splice, you actually remove the element from the array and you aren't just deleting the reference and making it null.

Something like this would work:

```
things.push(thing);
things.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding you want to use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), so things.push(yourThing);

Answer (score 1):

Adding to an array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Removing from an array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score -1):

I would use a loop.

```
var index;
var things= [];
for (index = 0; index < things.length; ++index) {
    text += things[index];
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes, this does not answer my question. You could add some if clause that would check if the element exists and then insert there, but I don't know if that is possible. This would have the advantage of defragmentation of indices.

Comment: did not understand your question then.