# delete operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

The book Javascript: The definitive guide states the following in it's 6th edition, in the chapter

> 4.13.3 The delete Operator

```
var a = [1,2,3]; // Start with an array
delete a[2]; // Delete the last element of the array
a.length // => 2: array only has two elements now
```

But when i tried the above snippet in Firefox and in chrome,
the array's length was still 3.

Is this a wrong information from the book or is the implementation of javascript in the browsers differ from a javascript spec?

**Note:**
I tried `splice` and it removed the element. My doubt is that is there a spec in ecmascript specifications that says delete should remove the element and the browsers decided not to implement according to that  script. or is the book wrong..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/760211 answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

Then to be wrong is your last assumption ("*array only has two elements now*"). As noted by RobG in comments this is wrong for two reasons:

- `Array.length` is the length of an array (see last **§15.4.5.2** cited later), not number of elements it contains.
- In your case `a.length` is not two but three because `delete` doesn't trim arrays.

What does it means? That comment is right (`a` has two elements) but code is wrong (array length is still three).

When you delete an element from an array what you get is `undefined` instead of that element (when you try to access that index):

```
var a = [1,2,3]; // a == [1, 2, 3]
delete a[2]; // a == [1, 2, undefined]
```

From [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

`delete` operator is described in **§11.4.1**. It says `[[Delete]]` array internal method it'll be called. Now we know (from **§8.6.2**) we should check `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` array internal method because simply deleting an index property is not enough. From **§15.4.5.1** we can see that `length` property can be changed to truncate array but it won't be affected deleting (removing) an array item because it won't do any assignment (then **§15.4.5.1** won't apply). You'll get `undefined` because now there isn't such member and according to **§8.6.1** result is then `undefined`.

In my opinion (but it's just speculation) confusion arises from **§15.4.5.2** where they say:

> The length property of this Array object is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable property whose name is an array index.

According to this single sentence then removing last element of an array *may* also reduce its length. This behavior doesn't fulfill **§15.4.5.1** and standard just states that `length` is *greater than...array index*, not exactly highest index + 1.

To summarize in simple words: `delete` operator simply *deletes* a member but `length` is unaffected.

Comment: thx for the answer :) I found what happens when the code is executed. But what bugs me is that, why is the book stating that the length would be 2. So my question is, is the implementation of javascript by chrome or firefox deviates from a ecmascript spec that says that delete should remove the element from the array..? is there even such a spec?

Comment: No, their implementation is correct (I don't know which book you're reading), let me search for a reference.

Comment: JavaScript: The Definitive Guide 6th edition by David Flanagan, Chapter 4.13.3 The delete Operator, Page number 84

Comment: `"When you delete an element from an array what you get is to replace that element with undefined"`. No, the property is removed entirely, what you get is `[1,2]` but the length is still 3, Try `a.hasOwnProperty('2')`. Attempting to access a non–existent member returns undefined though.

Comment: `Then to be wrong is your last assumption ("array only has two elements now")`. That "assumption" is absolutely correct, the array only has two elements.

Comment: @RobG I didn't add all citation, from question it is: "a.length // array has two elements now", obviously (?!) "elements" and "length" are used as synonyms here.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti—but they aren't synonyms, they are different things. The number of elements in an array is not necessarily the same as the length, an array can have a length of 1,000 and no elements at all. If you fix your answer I can delete the comments.

Comment: @RobG done, you're right it looks more clear pointing out that distinction.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti—this answer is still extremely confusing, the answer is really simple. The *delete* operator **deletes** the member, the length is unaffected. So there are two elements and the array has a length of three. That's it. No member is replaced with *undefined*, `a[2]` returns undefined because it attempts to access a non–existent member. Accessing any non–existent member returns *undefined*. The *length* is always **at least** one greater than the highest index, it can be any size bigger, e.g. `var a = new Array(100)` is an array with length 100 and no elements.

Comment: @RobG yes answer is very simple and OP knows it otherwise he didn't even post this question or it had to be closed as duplicate (for example of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)). What I tried to explain is the **reason** of that behavior and why book seems to be wrong according to language specification.