# Removing json Array from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here, I am deleting the particular Array [2] from the json object. But, what I am seeing in console is -- array values are **deleted** but it remains in the idx when I checked using `$.each` in jquery after deleted. So, How to delete the entire array object in a correct way?

```js
var obj = {
   equipments:'first',
 messages:['msg1','msg2','msg3'], 
}

console.log(obj);
$.each(obj.messages, function (idx, obj) { 
alert("before deleted index value" +idx);
});

obj1 = obj;

 if(obj1["equipments"] == 'first' ) {
      delete obj1.messages[2];
   }
   
console.log(obj1);
$.each(obj1.messages, function (idx, obj1) { 
alert("after deleted but index remains same" +idx);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Same as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `delete` on an array it doesn't remove that index, it sets the elment to `undefined` but the array length remains the same.

So you would use `splice()` but you will also need to realize that whatever you do to `obj1` will happen to `obj` also because `obj1` is a reference to `obj`. it is not a copy when you do `obj1=obj`

Comment: How can I use splice()? Can you please explain briefly? It would be helpful

Comment: `obj1.messages.splice(2, 1);`  first argument is start index, second is how many elements to remove

Comment: can see here what I mean about removing from one object does the same to the other http://jsfiddle.net/rs61z9gz/

Comment: also to avoid them being reference if you want a copy can do `obj1 = $.extend({},obj);`

Comment: For example purpose, I made like reference..Cool!

Comment: If I need to delete using substring(0,2). how can I achieve that? Ex: from the above example, I need delete ms from msg1, how can I use this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
obj1.messages.splice(2, 1); // at index 2, delete 1 element, inserting nothing
```

Comment: Appreciate Your work! But, I don't know exactly which index I need to delete. I am doing like comparing the values, based on the comparison, it will fetch the particular array index. Then, I am deleting the array. Here, you are using index 2 delete 1 element. What delete 1 means? I know index is 2

Comment: If you used `splice(2, 3, "f", "g")`, it would delete the elements at indices 2, 3 and 4 (three of them), and insert `"f"` and `"g"` at index 2 and 3 respectively. It would also change all indices of the following elements by -1, since we inserted one element less than we deleted. If you don't know which index you need to delete, how did you manage with `delete obj1.messages[2]` method, which also needs an index? Find the index, save the world.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Kudos for You and @
charlietfl .. Based on the time, I am checking his answer. Sorry for that! Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

for your current approach try using like this:

```
        $.each(obj1.messages, function (idx, obj1) { 
            if(typeof(obj1) != 'undefined')// log if the type of obj1 is not undefined because after delete the value will become undefined
        console.log("after deleted but index remains same" +idx);
        });
```

you can use **splice** in that case it will remove the index it self like this:

```
 if(obj1["equipments"] == 'first' ) {
             obj1.messages.splice(2, 1);
           }

    $.each(obj1.messages, function (idx, obj1) { 
        console.log("after deleted  index " +idx);
        });
```