# Delete elements of array based on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like this

```
var arrayFilterKeyValues=[{id:1,name:"one"},{id:2,name:"2"}..]
```

I have another array like this

```
var valuesArr=["1","2","3","4"...]
```

Now I am trying to delete elements from `arrayFilterKeyValues` if the id's are in `valuesArr`. This is the code I am using

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilterKeyValues.length; ++i) {
    var found = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < valuesArr.length; k++) {
        if (arrayFilterKeyValues[i].id == valuesArr[k]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        delete arrayFilterKeyValues[i];
    }
}
```

This is deleting the elements but when I check the array it has commas(`,`) in the array and when I check the length it is still showing the length of the array prior to deletion of elements. What am I doing wrong here? Need a solution compatible for IE8+

Comment: I don't see any JSON here, all I see is an array.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong here?"* You are not "properly" deleting the element from the array: [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/218196).

Comment: Deleting elements from an array doesn't *reorder* the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
arrayFilterKeyValues = arrayFilterKeyValues.filter(function (el) {
  return valuesArr.indexOf(el.id) === -1;
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/wajihi/1/edit?js,console)

jQuery version

```
arrayFilterKeyValues = $.grep(arrayFilterKeyValues, function (el) {
  return $.inArray(el.id, valuesArr) === -1;
});
```

**Update**

> when I check the array it has commas(,)

it happens because

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected.
>    [Deleting array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

Comment: @Praveen please look at this example http://jsbin.com/wajihi/4/edit?js,console, I've added couple possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` operator removes a property from an object.

In case of arrays when you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array and the element is not available in the array.

SOURCE: [CLICK HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

To remove elements from array use the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilterKeyValues.length; ++i) {
  var found = false;
  for (var k = 0; k < valuesArr.length; k++) {
      if (arrayFilterKeyValues[i].id == valuesArr[k]) {
          found = true;
          break;
      }
  }
  if (found) {
   var removedele = arrayFilterKeyValues.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that I found useful often when updating arrays in-place is the read-write:

```
var wp = 0, n=arrayFilterKeyValues.length;
for (var rp=0; rp<n; rp++) {
    if (valuesArr.indexOf(arrayFilterKeyValues[rp].id) == -1) {
        arrayFilterKeyValues[wp++] = arrayFilterKeyValues[rp];
    }
}
arrayFilterKeyValues.splice(wp);
```

i.e. keeping a writer pointer `wp` starting at 0 and doing an element copy `arr[wp++]=arr[rp]` operation for each element you want to keep. At the end you can resize the array.

With Javascript however the `filter` method of arrays already does this kind of operation with the only problem of returning a new independent array. Probably the efficiency gained by not allocating new elements is not worth the extra coding. Also the somewhat simpler

```
var new_arr = arrayFilterKeyValues.filter(function(x) {
                  return valuesArr.indexOf(x.id) == -1;
              });
arrayFilterKeyValues.splice(0);
arrayFilterKeyValues.push.apply(arrayFilterKeyValues, new_arr);
```

may be is even going to be more efficient despite doing extra memory allocation.

Instead of the `splice`/`push` operation may be a simple assignment to `arrayFilterKeyValues` is acceptable but note that you are not "updating" the array in this case, but assigning a new array to the same variable.

This is different if the same object is referenced in other places.