# How to properly delete object from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a javascript function which delete object from object array:

```
function RemoveFilter(filtArray,filtName) {
    var filtCount = filtArray.length;

    ...
    ...

    for (var i = 0; i < filtCount; i++) {
        var filter = filtArray[i];
        if (filter != undefined && filter.name == filtName) {
            delete filtArray[i];
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

It's works but I got a **big problem**. **Instead of removing** object completelly, it **leaves** undefined on its place (that why I have `filter != undefined` in my if).

So basically, if I am adding something after removal, I have not only new values but also those undefiled, and array is growing.

Probably my choise of object removing is poor but, how can I deal with this problem?
Considering that `filtArray[i].remove` not working at all.

Comment: You have missed the `()` on `remove()` function

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: For such a task an elegant solution, if you're using jQuery, would be using the .filter prototype as an alternative to the splice method. Is your array an associative array? **Check georg's solution below!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify an array in place, which is messy and error prone, just create a new array using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and assign it back to the original:

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name !== name
});
```

Comment: Oh darn, just said that above in the comments. This is a much cleaner solution instead of a .splice and it also is way more versatile, due to the fact that you might **slightly** edit that filter in order to delete more items providing a regular object. Bump that solution! +1

Comment: Thank you! This was the best one. No questionable splice and also allows to throw to oblivion "for".

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of delete. That should work.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2, 0, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

will give:

```
Banana,Orange,Lemon,Kiwi,Apple,Mango
```

If you don't want to add new elements while removing others, you might wanna do this;

```
fruits.splice(2, 1);
```

The result of fruits will be:

```
Banana,Orange,Lemon
```

Shamelessly copied from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

In your case,

```
function RemoveFilter(filtArray,filtName) {
    var filtCount = filtArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < filtCount; i++) {
        var filter = filtArray[i];
        if (filter != undefined && filter.name == filtName) {
            filtArray.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}
```

This will remove the i-th object and not leave an undefined hanging there.

Comment: An example that actually uses splice to **remove** items rather than insert new ones might be more useful.

Comment: Em and how it supposed to help? As I see in your example, it add new values and not removes them (also - how to do this in array?). Also, doit it update original array or what?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko, check now. I've added your scenario

Comment: @Olegs Corrected a mistake with the splice statement. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `splice()` is generally the way to go, and you can make it neat by doing something like this:

```
function removeFilter(filtArray, filtName) {
  var index = filtArray.indexOf(filtName);
  filtArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

You can read more about `splice()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

EDIT:

To show you an example:

```
var dog = {name: 'Spot', type: 'Dog'}; 
var cat = {name: 'Meow', type: 'Cat'}; 
var animals = [dog, cat];

removeFilter(animals, dog); // -> Removes the dog object from the array

console.log(animals) // -> Only has the cat object remaining
```