# Deleting and reusing array indexes

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, if I have a very large array, `myArray`

And I add to it by calling `myArray.push()`

And I remove indexes using something like `delete myArray[102]`

Is there some benefit or reason to create a separate array like `myArrayGaps` that holds which indexes in `myArray` are not being used so that if there are unused ones, I add to the array by defining a specific index like `myArray[102] = newValue;` instead of calling `.push()` and accumulating unused indexes?

Or is that impractical and pointless because of some aspect of Javascript's memory handling?

The reason I am deleting instead of splicing is because I don't want to reorder the indexes of the array; I am using them to identify specific objects at specific indexes. I'm primarily asking if there is any reason to optimize my use of the gaps made when using `delete`.

Comment: If you `.splice()` the array instead of doing `delete` you won't be left with gaps in the first place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: @Juhana see my comment on mohamedrias's answer below

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a property in array using `delete array[index]` will leave a hole.

Instead you can use `splice` property which will delete the value in that index and adjust the array size.

As you've mentioned,

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
delete a[2];
```

if you print `a` now, it will contain `[1, 2, undefined × 1, 4]`. `delete` removes the element but doesn't reindex the array/length.

But if you use splice instead,

```
a.splice(2,1);
```

It will return you `[1, 2, 4]`. So you won't find any hole.

Comment: the reason i'm deleting instead of splicing is because i don't want to reorder the indexes of the array; i am using them to identify specific objects at specific indexes. i'm primarily asking if there is any reason to optimize my use of the gaps.