# How to completely destroy a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, destroy

I am developing a game server with node.js, and I would want to store matchs inside a queue, in order to be able to destroy them after a certain timeout. Here is basically my implementation :

```
var matchs = [];

var createMatch = function () {
    matchs.unshift(new Match());
    matchs[0].start();

    setTimeout(function () {
        delete matchs[matchs.length - 1];
        matchs.pop();
    }, 5 * 1000);
};

function Match() {

    // ...

    this.foo = 0;

    this.start = function () {
        var self = this;

        setInterval(function () {
            console.log(self.foo++);
        }, 1 * 1000);
    };
}
```

What this code is supposed to do is, when I call `createMatch()`, display an increasing number every second, and stop after 5 seconds. However if I run this code, it will continue displaying numbers forever, which leads me to think that my Match objects are not destroyed properly.

Help please?

Comment: The object is actually an array, hence http://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/1169519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete` operator deletes a property but does not destroy an object nor any thing the object has created (like the interval). So your `setTimeout` could actually be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    matchs.pop().destroy();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

The `pop` removes the element from the array (no longer referenced and can be cleaned) but the `destroy()` is needed to to explicitly tell the `Match` object it needs to clean things up. In Javascript there is no way to do something when the object is *really* deleted from memory. There is no such concept.

So your `Match` object is responsible for keeping track of things it needs to clean afterwards like the example bellow:

```
    function Match() {
    this.intervalId = undefined;

    this.start = function () {
        ...
        this.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            ...
        }, 1 * 1000);
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        if (intervalId)  {
            clearInterval(this.intervalId);
        }
    }
}
```

Timeouts and intervals are a *resource* that can be *destroyed* by the appropriate functions. In this case `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clearInterval` to clean up an interval.

```
var handle = setInterval(..);
clearInterval(handle);
```

Simply deferencing the `Match` object will not cause the interval to stop because it's still running. Additionally that interval will keep a reference to the `Match` through the `self` variable.

Comment: So if I understand well, the object is not destroyed because it is still linked to an interval? When I clean every interval linked to it, is it deleted from memory?

Comment: Yes, when you dereference it in all scopes the variable will be garbage collected (when exactly depends on the implementation of the engine)