# Remove an object from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

am trying to remove an object from an Array list within a JavaScript object.

The Structure if the Object:

```
{
    "temp": {
        "name": "",
        "css": {
            "bg_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "part_bg_color": "xxxxx",
            "txt_font_family": "xxxxxxxx",
            "txt_font_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "headline_font_family": "xxxxx",
        },
        "part": [
            {
                "name": "xxxxxx",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "yyyyyy",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "zzzzzz",
                "style": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Code:

```
$.each(jsonData.temp.part, function(k, v) {
     var tt = this; //var tt = $(this)
     if( v.name === partName ){
          delete tt[k];
     }
});
```

Nothing happens.. no error, no warning!

Comment: What's the value of `partName`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements

Comment: Sorry,
here it is: 

var partName= $(this).prev().attr('name');
should be equal to the value of the key: 'name'
In this case: "xxxxxx" or: "yyyyyy"

Comment: You can [edit] your question with the [edit] link under the tags. :) But still that doesn't answer my question of what the actual _value_ is you are putting in. If you put `"aaaaaa"` in it will never do anything because there is no such _name_ in your data structure.

Comment: The current/actual value of partName is: "xxxxxx". so I want to remove the  first object with the name: "xxxxxx". thx!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your code. First, [`delete` does not remove elements. It only sets them to undefined. Use `splice`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/1331451) instead.

Second, it never gets to do that, because `tt` (or `this`) is the object inside the array that you are currently working on, not the array you are iterating. You need to access the array explicitly with its full name.

```
$.each(jsonData.temp.part, function(k, v) {
  var tt = this; //var tt = $(this)
  if( v.name === partName ){
    jsonData.temp.part.splice(k,1);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx! that's it. I missed this. you're right. tt  and/or this was not referring to the element I want to get.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could simply use a filter.

```
var o = {
    "temp": {
        "name": "",
        "css": {
            "bg_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "part_bg_color": "xxxxx",
            "txt_font_family": "xxxxxxxx",
            "txt_font_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "headline_font_family": "xxxxx",
        },
        "part": [
            {
                "name": "xxxxxx",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "yyyyyy",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "zzzzzz",
                "style": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}

o.temp.part = o.temp.part.filter(function (element) {return element.name !== "zzzzzz"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different approach, for example:

If the reference of the array is not needed, you can use reduce to create a new array:

```
jsonData.temp.part = jsonData.temp.part.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    if( value.name !== partName ){
          acc.push(value);
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
```

Also you can find the index of the element, and use splice to mantain the reference:

```
var indexElement = jsonData.temp.part.reduce(function(acc, value, index) {
    if( value.name !== partName ){
          return index;
     }
     return acc;
}, -1);

jsonData.temp.part.splice(indexElement, 1)
```

Both ways work.

Comment: Hi Quintana, Thx! the index of the element is: k. the suggestion with: splice did solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

The simplest way is to use delete.

```js
var jsonData = {
    "temp": {
        "name": "",
        "css": {
            "bg_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "part_bg_color": "xxxxx",
            "txt_font_family": "xxxxxxxx",
            "txt_font_color_main": "#xxxxx",
            "headline_font_family": "xxxxx",
        },
        "part": [
            {
                "name": "xxxxxx",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "yyyyyy",
                "style": {}
            },
            {
                "name": "zzzzzz",
                "style": {}
            }
        ]
    }
}

var nameToRemove = 'xxxxxx';
var parts = jsonData.temp.part;

$.each(parts, function(k, v) {
     
  if (v.name === nameToRemove)
    {      
      delete parts[k];
    }
     
});

//this code is added to just show the result

$.each(parts, function(i, r){
  
  if (r != undefined)
    {
       $('#result').append(r.name + ',')
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="result"></label>
```

Comment: @Jaya: Very useful & clean code snippet.. Thx! also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You created a copy and delete item from the copy.

```
$.each(jsonData.temp.part, function(k, v) {
    var tt = this; // now you created a new array!!!
    if( v.name === partName ){
         delete tt[k]; // here you delete the item from the copy array
         delete this[k]; // you remove item from the original array
    }
});
```