# Tracking the order checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created table that is filled with rows and columns of checkboxes.
Their unique id's are dynamically created as well.
I would like to store the order that the checkboxes are checked by the user in the checkboxs' values.
If a checkbox is unchecked, its value should be reset to "" or to "0".

It doesn't matter how many times a checkbox is checked and unchecked.
I only need the ultimate order, so an incrementing variable should work fine.

For example:

- There are checkbox1 - checkbox10 and all their values are initially set to "".
- If the user first clicked on checkbox3 its value would be set to "1".
- If the user then clicked on checkbox5 its value would be set to "2".
- If the user then clicked on checkbox8 its value would be set to "3".
- If checkbox3 and checkbox5 were unclicked, their values would be reset to "".
- If checkbox3 were checked yet again its value would be set to "4".
- It would not matter that there was no checkbox with a value of 1 or 2.

Comment: Code? Have you tried something?

Comment: Thing has to be worked with an array of checkbox ids... On check, push to array, on uncheck, remove from array if it's in. Show your code (HTML and JS) for more.

Comment: I don't know how to let a single script know which checkbox was checked so that it can address its value.

Comment: `$(".checkboxClass").click(function(){....});` This is the call from the check/uncheck to a script.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/a6fm7h9h/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkboxChecks = 1;

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      $this.val(checkboxChecks++);
    } else {
      $this.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb5" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb6" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb7" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb8" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb9" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="cb10" />
```

Comment: You should use the built in SO code snippet in your answer to make this runnable right in your answer, without an external fiddle.

Comment: This will lead to some skipped numbers... But may work well ;) +1

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the OP "It would not matter that there was no checkbox with a value of 1 or 2"

Comment: @SamBattat: To make it complete, if you wish, you could add some console.log() and check the "show console" in snippet editor. ;)

Comment: I just dropped the code in and everything worked perfectly with no adjustments! Thanks to you both.

Comment: @RockK You are welcome. Mark it as an answer if it helped you

Comment: I ran across a small snag. All of the rows that exist when the document loads work perfectly, but checkboxes in new rows created by the user pressing the "Add Row" button don't.

Comment: Thats because they are dynamically created, when you select these items they need to be selected by a static parent `$('<static parent>').on('<event>', '<dynamic element>', function(){....});` I'll update my answer soon

Comment: There are five checkboxes on each row of the tables. The tables are static even though they are initially unpopulated. So I would use these tables as a reference to find the checkboxes?

Is the checkbox change the "<event>" ? 

Thanks!

Comment: Correct. So for example `$('table').on('change', 'tr td .your-dynamic-checkbox', function(){ ..... });`'

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

If you don't have jQuery on your website, add this code first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then, add this (which should do the trick without any modifications):

```
<script>
var myCount = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            myCount.push($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).val(myCount.indexOf($(this).attr('id'))+1);
        }else{
            delete myCount[myCount.indexOf($(this).attr('id'))];
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this works, let me know!
Cheers

Comment: My idea was about storing the checkbox ids, like you did... But `delete` only sets the value to `undefined`. `splice` would be a better choice. [REF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500617/2159528). Then the index of the array could be correctly used.

Comment: Actually no, in my answer the "order" that he needs its being counted in the index of the array associated with the checkbox's id. Once you uncheck, you need to remove that checkbox's id from the array, without affecting the amounts of elements in it, so the only index associated to the id would be the last clicked. Using splice, by definition, would generate a new array with some missing elements, therefore the account would be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Just drawing from what others posted, this seems to work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var checkboxChecks = 10001;
   $('.myTablesClass').on('change', 'tr td .myInputsClass', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.is(':checked')) {
         $this.val(checkboxChecks++);
      } else {
         $this.val('');
      }
    });
});`
```