# Deleting an element from json array not resetting its length

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My issue is very simple.
I am trying to delete elements from a json array. 
I want to know when the last element is deleted in order to hide a `div`. So I do a check to find if `jsonArray.Length > 0`. 
The check is failing. The `jsonArray.Length` is not getting reset. It always keeps the number of elements added into it even after deleting all elements. For eg: if 4 elements are added to it, then the Length remains as 4.

I will post the code below.

**Initializers :**

```
var ccount = 1;
var tasks = []
```

**Inserting element into JSON array :**

```
function insertTask() {
        var out = '<div id="' + ccount + '" ><span style=" width:40px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align:left;"><img src="../Images/iconrequestreport1.png" /></span><span style="width:160px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-family:Arial; font-size:small;"><div>' +
                $('#drpTrajectory').find(":selected").text() + '</div><div>Start Time: ' +
                $('#txtStartTime').val() + '</div><div>End Time: ' +
                $('#txtEndTime').val() + '</div><div>Aggregation: ' +
                $('#drpAggrInterval').find(":selected").text() +
                '</div></span><span style="width:40px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><input id="btn' + ccount +
                '" class="btnDelete" type="button" onclick="deleteTask(' + ccount + ')"/></span></div> ';
        $('#divTravelTime').append(out);
        var obj = { TaskId: ccount, TrajectoryName: $('#drpTrajectory').find(":selected").text(), StartTime: $('#txtStartTime').val(), EndTime: $('#txtEndTime').val(), Aggregation: $('#drpAggrInterval').find(":selected").text() }
tasks.push(obj)

ccount++;
$('#divTravelTimeHeader').show();
$('#divTravelTime').show();
$('#divJobSubmit').show();

if (tasks.length > 0) {
    $('#divTaskView').show();
}
else {
    $('#divTaskView').hide();
}
```

**Code to delete an item from the JSON array :**

```
function deleteTask(tt) {
    var remID = "#" + tt;
    $(remID).remove();
    delete tasks[tt - 1];
    if (tasks.length > 0) {
        $('#divTaskView').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divTaskView').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this is marked as C# ?

Comment: Use `splice` to delete an element from an array.

Comment: See the difference between `delete` and `splice`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice

Comment: **delete arr[0]** sets the first item to *undefined*.  It does not remove the first item from arr

Comment: Please refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `delete` over array, it will replace the "deleted" element with undefined, but the index will remain the same.

```
let arr = [1, 2]
// arr.length is 2
delete arr[1]
// arr = [1, undefined], but the length is still 2
```

Use `splice` instead

Comment: Good. Thanks. But it doesn't answer my question exactly.

Comment: replace this line: `delete tasks[tt - 1];` with this `tasks.splice(tt-1 , 1);`

Comment: @ViVi, If you did **arr[1] = undefined;** would you expect the length of **arr** to change? Check out the link by Patrick Steele in your original question for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

update :
Check it now , the splice method removes the rest elements in the array , from the specified index .

```
function deleteTask(tt) {
    var remID = "#" + tt;
    $(remID).remove();

    //delete tasks[tt - 1];
    tasks.splice(tt-1);

    if (tasks.length > 0) {
        $('#divTaskView').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divTaskView').hide();
    }
}
```

Code to delete an item from the JSON array :

```
function deleteTask(tt) {
    var remID = "#" + tt;
    $(remID).remove();

    //delete tasks[tt - 1];
    tasks = tasks.splice(tt-1 , 1);

    if (tasks.length > 0) {
        $('#divTaskView').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#divTaskView').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: `splice` deletes in place, and returns the deleted values. So you **should, in this case, not** write `tasks = tasks.splice()`.

Comment: Justo to complete the answer. Instead of splice(tt-1, 1), use slice(tt-1) to return the rest of the array. Or use delete myArray[1]