# Dynamically creating and removing data-bound model inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a `Recipe` model which contains an array of `Flavor`s.

```
export class Flavor {
    name: string;
    base: Base;

    removeFlavor(flavor: Flavor) : void {
        for (let f in this.flavors) {
            if (this.flavors[f][0] == flavor) {
                delete this.flavors[f];
            }
        }
    }
}

export class Recipe {
    strength: number;
    flavors: [Flavor, number][];
}
```

I'm trying to bind these variable number of flavors to inputs which can be dynamically added and removed from the recipe. Is there a feature in Angular 2 that supports this? Here is what I have so far:

```
<h3>Flavors</h3>

<div *ngFor="let flavor of mix.recipe.flavors" class="flavor">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="flavor[0].name">

    <label>Strength <i>(percent)</i></label>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="flavor[1]" min="0" max="1" step=".00001">

    <label>Base</label>
    <label *ngFor="let base of bases; let value = index;">
        {{ base }}
        <input type="radio" [checked]="value === flavor[0].base" (click)="flavor[0].base = value">
    </label>

    <a href="#" (click)="mix.recipe.removeFlavor(flavor)">Remove Flavor</a>
</div>

<a href="#" (click)="/* create new flavor */">New Flavor</a>
```

`Remove Flavor` should remove the `Flavor` from the `Mix` and also remove the entire `div.flavor` associated with it. `New Flavor` should create a new `Flavor` in `Mix` and append a new, bound `div.flavor` to the end of the list.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is or the question is about. With `(click)="xxx(...)"` you get `xxx()` called and there you can remove the item from `flavors`. `*ngFor` then also automatically removes the `<div>`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when putting `mix.recipe.removeFlavor(flavor)` in the click event, it removes the flavor from the recipe object but not the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `splice()` instead of `delete`

See also [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)