# Why don't arrays in Javascript resize when you remove an item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In many languages, the standard dynamic list (not fixed-size array) type will resize after an item is deleted:

**Python:**

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
del(myList[0])
print(len(myList)) # Prints '2'
```

**C#:**

```
var myList = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"};
myList.RemoveAt(0);
Console.WriteLine(myList.Count); // Prints '2'
```

and so on.

However, in Javascript, the list length stays the same, even though the element evaluates to `undefined` ([this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements) tells me that it's different to `array[index] = undefined`):

**Javascript:**

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
delete myArray[0]
console.log(myArray.length) // Prints '3'
console.log(myArray) // Prints "[ , 'b', 'c' ]" in node, '[undefined × 1, "b", "c"]' in Chrome

myArray[0] = undefined
console.log(myArray) // Prints "[ undefined, 'b', 'c' ]" on both node and Chrome

myArray.splice(0, 1)
console.log(myArray) // Prints "['b', 'c']"
```

My questions are:

- Is the JS array `delete` behaviour by design or an oversight that couldn't be fixed for fear of breaking legacy code?
- What exactly is the 'undefined-like' value that replaces the deleted array element?

Comment: *(I should have realized this was a duplicate. That dupetarget goes on my list for next time... :-) )*

Comment: In JavaScript the `delete` instruction is not array specific. It's an instruction that you can use on all JS objects to delete a specific property. It means `delete` doesn't delete an item in an array but deletes the key (array object's property) and turns the array into a sparse one. In JS this is the only way to turn a dense array into a sparse one by removing an item. So it's valuable.

Comment: an undefined slot has the value of undefined, but hasOwnProperty will reveal all. rememember that object keys don't vouch for object values, one of which can be _undefined_, which is the same "return" as asking for a non-existing property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison of `delete` to `RemoveAt` and such is incorrect. `delete` doesn't do what they do; to do that, you'd use `splice`:

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myArray.splice(0, 1);
console.log(myArray.length) // Prints '2'
```

`delete` removes the entry without reordering other entries, creating a *sparse* array (an array with some entries missing entirely). `delete` isn't really meant for arrays, it's meant for removing properties from objects; but it applies to arrays because standard (e.g., non-typed) arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)*, they're objects with special handling for certain properties, such as those whose names are "array indexes" (which are [defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type) as string names "...whose numeric value `i` is in the range `+0 ≤ i < 2^32-1`") and `length`.

`length`'s value is changed if you:

- Use any method to add or remove entries (`splice`, `push`, etc.).
- Add an entry by assigning to an index equal to or greater than `length`.
- Assign directly to `length`: If you increase `length`, you make the array sparse; if you decrease it, you remove any entries at that index or above. E.g., if you have an array `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and do `theArray.length = 3`, it won't have entries at indexes 3 (`'d'`) or 4 (`'e'`) anymore.

> Is the JS array delete behaviour by design or an oversight that couldn't be fixed for fear of breaking legacy code?

By design. As mentioned above, `delete` is primarily about removing properties from objects.

> What exactly is the 'undefined-like' value that replaces the deleted array element

There isn't one. This is another by-product of the fact standard arrays are objects: If you try to read the value of a property from an object that it doesn't have, the result of that "get" operation is the value `undefined`. It's not that there's something in the object with an `undefined`-like value, it's that there's no property in that object with that name at all. This illustration may be useful:

```js
var o = {}; // A non-array object
console.log(o.noSuchProperty);    // undefined
console.log(o["noSuchProperty"]); // undefined
console.log(o[2]);                // undefined

var a = []; // An array object
console.log(a.noSuchProperty);    // undefined
console.log(a["noSuchProperty"]); // undefined
console.log(a[2]);                // undefined
```

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: Ah, interesting! I was confusing the REPL representation of the array with its actual value, since the Chrome output at least implies there's something to do with `undefined`, when in reality it's just telling you there's nothing there. I also didn't know that `length` was settable, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

As you mentioned using `delete` will not remove the element, but instead just set it to undefined. `Splice, unshift or pop` however, will remove that block from the array.

Comment: "but instead just set it to undefined" --- that's not technically correct. When a property is deleted - it's deleted. Setting it to `undefined` is different to that.

Comment: an undefined slot has the value of _undefined_, bur `hasOwnProperty` will reveal all