# Typescript: Length of empty array not zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array which has a single element which I delete with the following code:

```
delete array[0]
```

At this point the array is empty. I'm therefore confused why `array.length` has an output of `1`.

When I use `console.log` it displays the following:

[image: console.log]

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or how do I check that the array is empty? Maybe an explanation of typescript array memory management would be useful.

Comment: Read the [Description for `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description) which reads `... the delete operator has nothing to do with directly freeing memory`. So in your case, it deleted the value but not the memory used by the array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have explained why this is not a duplicate in the question

Comment: Also it doesn't make sense on the face of it because *"TypeScript array memory management"* isn't a thing. TS compiles to JS, remember; there's no TypeScript at runtime.

Comment: While I agree your question is not an exact duplicate, the linked questions & answers do actually provide some interesting insight and it feels like they also answer your question. I tried to formulate something more specific, feel free to comment more if I am not understanding your needs correctly.

Comment: it's explained in the Deleting array elements section https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

**You should not use `delete` to remove an element of an array if you expect it to shrink.**

Basically it will remove the reference for the first element, but won't shrink the array.

element [0] is empty -> array appears as `[empty]`, because there is one *empty* spot in the array ! The size is still reserved in memory. And the length property is still 1.

**So, this is not an *empty array*, it's a non-empty array with one *empty spot***

Other example :

```
var a = [3, 4];
delete a[0];
```

`a` in my JS console results as `[empty, 4]` .

---

> Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or how do I check that the
>   array is empty?

If you want to check if such an array is only containing `empty`s, you could could simply filter for undefined values :

```
var a = [3, 4];
delete a[0];
delete a[1];
if (a.filter(x => x !== undefined).length === 0) {
  console.log('array looks empty!');
} else {
  console.log('array doesn't look empty!');
}
```

(but of course this won't work if you have actual `undefined` values that have some meaning, I hope it is not the case)

---

> Maybe an explanation of typescript array memory management would be
>   useful.

It 's quite simple : there is no TypeScript memory management.

As already pointed out in comments, TypeScript is turned to Javascript, at runtime it is only JavaScript running, it's Javascript arrays and nothing more.

There is nothing special that Typescript is doing for you here. This will be transpiled *verbatim* to javascript.

---

For more info on the JS arrays and delete, see linked potential duplicate questions for details and explanations :

- [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)
- [Why don't arrays in Javascript resize when you remove an item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325887/why-dont-arrays-in-javascript-resize-when-you-remove-an-item)
- [Javascript object with array, deleting does it actually remove the item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495764/javascript-object-with-array-deleting-does-it-actually-remove-the-item)