# Get the minimum value from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to get the minimum value from an array without changing the way the the value are aligned.

```
function removeSmallest(numbers){
var min=Math.min.apply(null,numbers);
var indexvalue=numbers.indexOf(min);
delete numbers[indexvalue];
return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. `Math.min.apply(null, numbers)` should be `Math.min.apply(Math, numbers)` (note `Math` instead of `null`)
2. Normally, `delete` is not the right tool for arrays (see [this question's answers for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice); use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove array entries if you're going to modify the array in place:

   ```
   numbers.splice(indexvalue, 1);
   ```

You might also consider creating and returning a *new* array instead of mutating and returning the same array you received.