# Delete arrayItem[index] leaves the element placeholer as undefined

Tags: javascript

```
delete addon_categories[index];
```

If index is 1, this statement leaves an undefined placeholder in the array.

```
[{Object}, undefined]
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice

Comment: In that case use Array.splice method.SHare your array for more insight

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting array elements in JavaScript - delete vs splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/deleting-array-elements-in-javascript-delete-vs-splice)

Comment: delete will delete the object property, but will not reindex the array or update its length. So for your case `splice(startIndex, itemsToDelete)` is what you need.

Comment: This is expected behavior.

Comment: just use array.splice for this specific case, likely `addon_categories.splice(index, 1)`, where I currently suppose that index is 1.

Comment: All you're doing is deleting the value of that element of the array, not the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (index > -1) {
   addon_categories.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Using `delete` keyword, it will set `undefined`, will not remove the element complete it's expected behavior.